# Can questions be "shared" within sites?

Tags: discussion, cross-posting

Most questions on Math.SE clearly belong on this site, while others are perhaps better answered elsewhere. But there are questions that, it seems to me, really fit well in more than one site. An example is https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/3716/is-mathematics-always-correct, which was migrated from Math. Now, I am not asking whether that specific question should have been left in one site or another, but rather, in those rare situations where a question would clearly benefit from more than one community, is there a way of having it be in more than one site? I am not talking about reposting, but rather have it be "shared". (Perhaps there are reasons I haven't considered why this is undesirable.)

Comment: This meta.SO question might be relevant: [Is cross-posting a question on multiple Stack Exchange sites permitted if the question is on-topic for each site?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/)

Comment: See also the recent question [What, when and will we migrate questions to MO 2.0?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/4880/242)

Comment: (a) you may want to mark it feature request (b) I think all the hurdles for your proposal would be on the technical side: how to implement voting for objects shared between two sites etc.

Comment: Another example in the same vein: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/531/what-is-ultrafinitism-and-why-do-people-believe-it

Comment: Another: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/255856/how-do-mathematicians-think-about-the-existence-of-numbers

Comment: And http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/261860/how-to-introduce-advanced-set-theoretical-objects-to-philosophy-students

Comment: And http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/270665/looking-for-philosophical-subject-for-my-bachelor-thesis