# Requests for Reopen & Undeletion Votes, etc. (volume 10/2012 - 12/2014)

Tags: discussion, re-open, big-list, undeletion

The purpose of this thread is to help focus the attention of the community on posts that may require exceptional handling. This includes requests for reopen and undeletion votes. A request should be posted as an answer below.

Please do not use this thread to engage in debates on contentious matters (e.g. reasons for closure). That should be done in a separate linked thread. The goal is to keep *this* meta thread free of tension, so that everyone feels comfortable posting here. Please be polite, and respect the many different viewpoints in our diverse community.

To inform readers of the current (and past) states of the targeted post, please append tags such  [REOPENED,RECLOSED] or [UNDELETED] at the start of the answer.

Beware that "short" requests such as "request reopening of <*link*>" may be automatically converted to comments by the SE software, so you may need to write more (e.g. why you think that the question should be reopened or undeleted).

Comment: For reopen requests that are run-of-the-mill (e.g. aren't meant to debate reasons for closure), do you think it would make sense to have a generic reopen-request thread, so that we don't end up with hundreds or thousands of questions on such. Then each request would simply be an answer in the reopen thread, and it being bumped would get the same exposure as a new question. Thoughts? Unless I hear any objections I will create such a thread.

Comment: @Bill: Yes. This crossed my mind after posting this. I agree that it would be a good idea.

Comment: I didn't expect that you would edit this specific question into the general question (I was writing another). But since it is done, we may as well go with it.

Comment: @Bill: I saw no reason to wait with that idea. There was no actual discussion in this thread anyway.

Comment: Request reopening of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/233353/non-physical-jounce-examples

Comment: Aaaargh! Come on, software, give me a break! It says, "Please post general requests for reopen votes as answers below." Well, that's exactly what I did, and you decided my answer was "trivial", and converted it to a comment. Don't do that!

Comment: @Gerry: This new development seems to be another one of those "features" that serves sites like SO well, but is an unalloyed nuisance here... yecch.

Comment: @Gerry: The solution would be to add a few words, I suppose. For example why it should be reopened.

Comment: @Asaf, I opted for cursing the darkness rather than lighting a candle. Anyway, the question has been reopened.

Comment: @Gerry: Darkness is just the light's way of proving the empty set exists.

Comment: @Bill: (and others who wish to comment) Should we delete the requests that has been resolved? None of the sorting methods (active, oldest, votes) are guaranteed to bring up the requests that have not been dealt with. If we keep all the satisfied requests they will make the noise to signal ratio huge. Also since deletions aren't "hard" all 10K+ and mods can read the history if necessary.

Comment: @Willie: I think that we should delete *old* reopening requests and perhaps have one post/additional thread for indexing them. I should also think that any request older than $n$ days for some reasonable $n$ should be deleted. If something has not been reopened and the initial votes expired... well, it makes sense to conclude that there aren't that many people interested in reopening.

Comment: @Willie It's probably useful to have some nontrivial history remain so that folks $\rm < 10K$ can gain some idea about what types of questions do get reopened, and what types don't. By quickly scanning the requests it might help to convey some idea of the community consensus on marginal topics. To keep the unopened requests at the top of the active sort, they could easily be bumped if there is still interest.

Comment: @Bill: Good point. Bumping does seem like a good idea.

Comment: I think we should delete answers with the post being reopened. They are not relevant and we need to scroll way down to see new requests

Comment: @Belgi: This is why I prefer to browse Meta with [answers sorted by activity](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/7071/856).

Comment: @Belgi Sorting by activity solves the problem. I just bumped the only active discussion to the top with an edit. There are two requests dated by November 2012, which I guess are no longer ongoing conversations (but anyone so inclined can bump them; it's a CW).

Comment: Thanks for the workaround, I still think theres no reasons for this to log all reopen request that were/will be made

Comment: @AsafKaragila Shouldn't closed questions get a link to this meta page ?

Comment: Per the (short) discussion in [this deleted meta post](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/16264/requests-for-undelete-votes), I have edited this thread to support requests for votes to undelete as well as votes to reopen.

Comment: I unprotected the post, since I think we're safe from "thank you" junk, and I do think that new users should be able to come in and pitch their requests.

Comment: Should we flag obsolete "answers" for deletion after a while? And as what? "Not an answer"?

Comment: @Tobias: I think not; if only so that there is a visible log as to what has been going on in the past. Just order the answers by activity and watch the top of the thread.

Comment: The question got protected again; I'd assume, but cannot check, since it fulfills [criteria for autoprotection](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89532/automatically-protect-questions-with-three-or-more-low-rep-user-deleted-answers/89971#89971) The simplest way out would be to restart a question of this form. IMO this would be desirable regardless the protection issue.

Comment: @quid: C'mon, we're only at 200 answers. Let's wait until there are at least 500.

Comment: Mainly, I just wanted to signal the protection issue and an easy way out.

Comment: @quid: Yes, yes, I see that protection triggering every time I remove it. But I gave it some more thought, and for now it seems harmless after all.

Answer (score 11):

[REOPENED]

I would like to request [Motivation for the Tensor Product](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/332011/400) be reopened as I do not think it is a duplicate of and [Motivation for Tensor Product](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/18881/400).

The latter question asks "We already have Direct Product, Semi-direct products, so after all why do we need Tensor Product?", which is a question about why multilinearity is in general useful.

The former question (which was closed as a duplicate) asks "What's the reason/motivation to define the tensor product using the free vector space and that quotient to impose linearity? Can someone point me out the motivation for that definition?". These are questions about the specific construction of the tensor prodct, and NOT the general usefulness of multilinearity properties.

Comment: I think one thing that would help is if the two questions are edited to they have more precise and more distinct (from each other) titles.

Comment: I edited the question titles. It only took a year and a half to disambiguate.

Answer (score 9):

[UNDELETED]

Request for undeletion, or explanation of deletion:

https://math.stackexchange.com/a/898051/, a "hint" answer that does substantial work toward solving the differential equation in the question [Differential equation $\sin \theta \frac{dr}{d \theta}+r\cos \theta =\tan \theta,0<\theta<\pi/2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/898048/differential-equation-sin-theta-fracdrd-thetar-cos-theta-tan-theta).  The answer received comments that it should be a comment, but I disagree.  Substantial contributions toward solving the problem are often fine as answers, even if they do not go through the full details of a write-up of a solution.  (Comments included a nonsensical one selected from a review queue.)  It might be relevant that the answer was posted before the other, more detailed ones.

A moderator deleted it, so regular users cannot vote to undelete.  I'm requesting that a moderator undelete it, and would be interested in explanations of why people think such an answer should be deleted.

Comment: I second this plea. An IMHO good hint started getting negative flags for some reason. I voted to dismiss the flag, but apparently that didn't carry enough weight. May be there is an anti-hint faction? It may be that the entire question were to be deleted for not showing effort, but singling out this answer sends a wrong message. For the record: it has six upvotes and no downvotes.

Comment: I think the deeper question is why a moderator deleted it - there is likely to be something going on beside the anti-hint comments. They may not be able to give full info. Of course the comments are not in accord with the usual norms of this site - hints are perfectly fine.

Comment: Thank you for bringing this to my attention. I don't know what I had been thinking. I see that there were a large number of flags on that post, and I suspect I trusted them too much. I've undeleted the answer.

Answer (score 6):

[REOPENED]

(Also, as pointed out by Asaf in a comment below, this was a duplicate request.  My apologies for the inadvertent dupliaction.)

---

The question ["If every convergent subsequence converges to a then so does the original sequence"](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/776899) should be reopened (in my opinion).

It is a request for clarification/explanation of an argument from a text.

It was closed as off-topic since it is essentially a repost of an earlier, deleted question.  The thing is: this earlier question was deleted by the Community User, hence cannot be reopened by 10K+ voters.  My view is that the earlier question was reasonable as well; if it could be reopened, then I agree that the current version should be closed as a duplicate, and the earlier one revised for clarity and reopened.   Since that doesn't seem to be possible, I have voted to reopen the current question, and I would ask others to do likewise.

---

In general, it seems a bit unreasonable to me that the OP has been put in a Catch-22, in which their current question is being closed essentially as a duplicate of an earlier question which is unable to be undeleted/reopened.

Comment: See also http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/13566/622

Comment: @AsafKaragila: Dear Asaf, Thanks, I hadn't seen this.  (I somehow missed it when looking down the list.)  I'll try to sort out the duplication of posts soon (although I have to rush out right now).  Regards,

Answer (score 5):

[REOPENED] [Show that floating point $\sqrt{x \cdot x} \geq x$ for all long $x$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/237865/show-that-floating-point-sqrtxx-x-for-all-long-x)

I would like to see this question reopened. I believe it is a valid numerical analysis question.

Comment: See also [this question](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/6590/242) about the closure of the above question.

Answer (score 5):

I am trying to get

[Let $G$ be a finite abelian group. Let $a\in G$ be an element of maximal order. Prove $|b|$ divides $|a|$ for all $b\in G$. A different proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/290211/let-g-be-a-finite-abelian-group-let-a-in-g-be-an-element-of-maximal-order)

reopened. It was closed as a duplicate of [Prove that for any element $b$, $|b|$ divides $|a|$ (order of $b$ divides order of $a$).](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/191981/prove-that-for-any-element-b-b-divides-a-order-of-b-divides-order)  and [Finite abelian group generated by elements of maximal order](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/271162/finite-abelian-group-generated-by-elements-of-maximal-order). True the question has been answered, but I haven been given another outline of a proof for this and would really appreciate it if i could get some feedback on this version of the proof for this question

Answer (score 5):

[REOPENED]

[Is a line just an infinitely large circle?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1068447/12952)  (formerly [Whats wrong with this?](https://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/1068447/1))

I'll repeat the same thing here that I said in the comments:

> To the closers and other downvoters, please consider that although it is stated in layman's terms, the idea behind it is a deep question about Moebius transformations / stereographic projection (or if you think I'm stretching, at least basic topology). In particular, even if you don't believe the question is stated well, it could inspire a very good answer. –

I fixed up the wording a little bit to help the OP come off less abrasive to mathematician sensibilities.  (And changed the title.)

This is the type of question I would ***really like to see stay open*** on MSE: genuine curiosity about a mathematical intuition by a layman.  Even if it looks little lazy on the surface, I think we need to encourage non-homework questions from non-mathematicians as much as possible.

Comment: As a side note, if this gets reopened, does anybody have any ideas on what tags to use here?

Comment: Mike Miller just tagged - rather appropriately, I'd say - with [tag:projective-geometry].

Comment: Thank you! Although the topology part I did unaware that it was a topology question.

Answer (score 4):

[REOPENED] I would like this question:

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/243115/field-extensions-of-cos-and-sin

to be reopened. The question was closed as a duplicate of [Degree of field extension](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/239425/degree-of-field-extension). Bit IMO, the questions are different. The closed one is about whether a specific proof is correct, not just a question about how to prove it (like the other question).

Answer (score 4):

[Re-opened] I'd like to suggest reopening [What is importance of the Bunyakovsky conjecture?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/78911/what-is-importance-of-the-bunyakovsky-conjecture). The question in the body, "how important do you consider the answer to this problem", may well be "too soft", but the question in the title seems to me to be a solid mathematical question.

Comment: I cast the fifth and final vote.

Answer (score 4):

[REOPENED] (Thanks.)

[This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/385310/462). I think that there may be insights that only working mathematicians could provide (as opposed to philosophers), and even if there are wildly differing points of view, seeing them described may be useful.

I understand that the question is not mathematical in the sense that "how do I integrate such-and-such" or "why is this number divisible by that one" are. I also believe its answers may be more interesting and useful in the long run.

Of course, it may be that answering the question in detail, considering as many of its subtleties as possible would just be too long and unfeasible. That's fine; even providing a few references and ideas that can potentially be fleshed out would be more useful that simply dismissing it.

[Related](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6190/462).

Comment: I'll do my best to improve this question.

Answer (score 4):

[REOPENED] [This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/453677/eulers-phi-function-phin-is-even-for-all-n-geq-3-when-is-it-not-divisi) should be re-opened as the OP has edited the post to try to tell us what they have done.

Answer (score 4):

[REOPENED] Thank you.

The question was undeleted by the OP, and has now been closed. I think it does more good being open and have myself voted to reopen. As I told the OP elsewhere, "The thing is, many (oh so many!) people think that mathematics is just about computations (long and tedious and often times pointless). And many among those that know better think that the only way to use a computer is to help with these computations. But there is much more to math than that, and many more uses of a computer in mathematical research. And there are the incompleteness theorems, showing that not all mathematical practice can be automated anyway. Good answers to your question could be quite insightful!"

---

This question was actually deleted, but I think it is interesting and can be useful to many, not just the OP: [Why are there mathematicians that do not use computers?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/465109/462)

> I was watching a video on Andrew Wiles and his proof of Fermat's Last Theorem and I quite liked the video, especially the complexity of the proof only to prove a simple concept which can be understood by most people. I also liked the graphics they used to illustrate elliptic curves and modular forms.
>
> But then Andrew Wiles said that he never uses a computer, he only uses pen and paper and I also heard of other mathematicians that don't use computers.
>
> Do they not use computers because there are problems only a mathematicians can solve or are there other motives? Wouldn't the proof have taken much less than 7+ years if he used a computer?

I have voted to undelete. I am posting this request here as it seems a natural extension of the intention of this post. Also, if there are issues with the question, this may be the place to address them, which may also prove useful on its own.

Comment: I would not undelete a question that the OP him/herself deleted.

Comment: @Thomas That's fine. In this case, I believe the deletion happened because of the downvote, which I consider unwarranted. Regardless, I think (as I said) that the question can be useful to many, not just to the OP, which should (surely?) be our main consideration.

Comment: I agree that the question with answers could be useful. But, on principal grounds, I believe that it is wrong to undelete a question that the OP him/herself deleted. I think a better approach is for someone else to repost the question. I don't think that we should assume we know why someone decides to delete his/her own question.

Comment: The OP undeleted the question themselves. See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/465133/rigour-in-mathematics#comment1001727_465133).

Comment: Ok, I didn't know that. In that case I see no problem.

Answer (score 4):

I think that the

[1+1+1+1 ...= -1/2](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/648665/36639)

question, which at present is a merger of an older 1 upvote/1 (not so highly voted) answer Math SE question and a two days ago migrated from from Physics 5 upvotes/highly upvoted answers question, should be reopend as there is IMHO nothing unclear about the OP asking for an (intuitively understandable) proof that $ 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 \cdots = -\frac{1}{2}$.

Answer (score 4):

[REOPENED]

The question [Is there a highest order of infinity?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/806064/462) was closed as a duplicate. Its original version asked whether "there is a limit to the orders of infinity", something that has been asked here several times already. The person asking the question has since clarified that what they are asking for is something very different,

> Does there exist an infinite set of cardinality such that it can never be reached by taking power sets of a set with cardinality aleph-null?

(By the way, if reopened, an answer may as well clarify that $\beth_{\omega}$ is far from being "highest" among the infinite cardinalities.)

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/666469/are-there-any-infinites-not-from-a-powerset-of-the-natural-numbers for a possible duplicate of the version.

Comment: I figured, but it still seemed better to have the question point to the right preimage. (I won't vote to close since it seems unnecessarily cruel, though.)

Answer (score 4):

[REOPENED]

I do not agree with the closure of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/954188/how-can-i-find-objects-behind-my-camera).

While the user does not have enough mathematical sophistication himself to formulate the question as one in analytic geometry, the description of the problem is clearly one of mathematics. So I don't see how it can be closed as off-topic. (I would vote to re-open myself if it weren't for my binding mod powers.)

Furthermore, it appears that the user encountered the problem in a real-life scenario and so he provided context.

The fact that the question does admit [a simple mathematical answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/954188/how-can-i-find-objects-behind-my-camera#comment1964831_954188) should not be held against the original asker: we were all ignorant once.

Answer (score 4):

[REOPENED]

[This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/396170/evaluating-int-0-infty-frac-log-1x1x2dx) was closed as a duplicate of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/155941/evaluate-the-integral-int-01-frac-lnx1x21-mathrm-dx).  But it's not a duplicate.  The limits of integration are different.

Comment: Although the substitution $x\mapsto 1/x$ takes it a long way to the duplicate target, IMO the remaining difference is large enough to not call it a duplicate.

Answer (score 3):

[REOPENED]
The question [How to define a well-order on $\mathbb R$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/220066/how-to-define-a-well-order-on-mathbb-r) were closed recently due to the confusing nature of the word "define".

If by "define" we wish to mean "explicitly describe without any appeal to the axiom of choice" then it is indeed a duplicate. However as the comments clarify, this is not the case.

I believe, if so, that it is not a duplicate of the question it was closed as a duplicate of (or any of the questions in the links in the comments I posted, as well).

---

Thank you [Andres Caicedo](/users/462/andres-caicedo), [rschwieb](/users/29335/rschwieb), [Belgi](/users/21335/belgi), [Matt Pressland](/users/25159/matt-pressland).

Comment: That depends on what your definition of is is.

Comment: @Graphth: The answer on that depends on what is your definition of definition.

Answer (score 3):

[REOPENED] I would like to see the question on [*"mathematics in the movies"*](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/242390/films-about-math-a-question-about-math-education-and-motivation-for-learning-ma/) reopened. It asks about feature films depicting math, and/or mathematicians. I think it is *at least* as relevant to math, and this site, as are many other "soft questions" that still stand as open.  After all, we DO have tags "math history", "education", "big-list", etc.. If questions relevant to those tags are thereby subject to closure, then the tags should be removed from this site; else, they are appropriate topics on which to post.

If reopened, I think it might very well be appropriate to "wikify" the post (community wiki), but this question has merit.

---

ADDED, to answer Marvis's comment below: This post is not a "strict subset" of the post to which Marvis provides a link. They are sufficiently different posts to warrant separate consideration. (See for example, Rahul's reply to Marvis).

Comment: I adjusted the link to direct to the question rather than to your answer, this is more fitting to the thread, and makes it easier to reopen/comment/etc. on the actual question.

Comment: Thank you, @Asaf (When trying to access the question, I clicked on my answer from my user page, scrolled up, copied and pasted the link - I intended to link directly to the Question!)

Comment: I would like the part about "what kind of stories would you like to see in the future" removed as it is discussiony and off-topic. I said that in my comment on the question, but the asker chose to ignore it and freak out instead.

Comment: I believe that this question is a strict subset of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/18843/list-of-interesting-math-videos-documentaries

Comment: @Marvis: It seems to me the questions are split along fiction/nonfiction lines.

Comment: @Will Yes, rep is nice. But I already made my answer CW. My request to re-open was more about opening the question, not about gaining rep. I just thought there was a conflict of interest, in having drawn attention to a question I happened to answer.

Comment: *points to [comment](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/6424/requests-for-reopen-votes#comment23614_6628) that has been ignored yet again*

Answer (score 3):

[[MIGRATED](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/45807/what-are-the-chances-my-wife-has-lupus)] I would like to see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/256079 reopened.

- The stated reason for the closure ("not constructive") does not apply. There were answers, and they were supported by facts. The question did not solicit debate or arguments. There was a meta-debate, but it was about the appropriateness of the question, not its content; considering such a debate as a reason for closure would be circular, as one could then get questions closed simply by starting a debate on whether they should be closed. Nor is there any reason to expect that the question will solicit debate or arguments in the future. The question does fit our Q&A format; a question was posed and answers were given; that the answers were of the form "the question can't be answered because there's not enough information" is quite a common occurrence and not a reason for closure.
- The stated reason for the closure bears no relationship to the reasons for closure given in the comments. The reasons given in the comment are not valid reasons for closure. Personal opinions on whether the OP should or shouldn't try to assess the chances of his wife having a serious disease by asking a question on a math Q&A site shouldn't enter into the decision whether this question is suitable for this site. It's the OP's decision and not ours whether he wants to ask this question here.
- There were two answers at the time of closure, which had several upvotes and contained information potentially valuable to the OP. Even those who commented on problematic aspects of asking such a question on such a site can hopefully agree that it's good if the OP knows that there's not enough information in his question to answer the question.
- I don't know the current status of the close vote cancelling policy proposal; it may or may not be relevant that I cast a no-close vote in a comment, no-one cancelled it and it received three upvotes.

Comment: If you have a homework problem, you post it on m.se; if you have a life-or-death problem, you don't spend your time m.se, you hire a professional. That's the advice this person needs, and it can be given as a comment; there's no need for an answer. I don't want to think about the consequences for m.se should someone, in good faith, give a misleading answer which causes some real harm.

Comment: @Gerry: My main point is that this is for the OP to decide, not for us. It seems that you and others disagree (though I don't think any argument against that principle has been offered yet), so I'll argue on the merits even though I think we shouldn't: Many questions are life or death questions. If someone posts a question on how to optimize a process and save the government a lot of money, that money can be invested in better hospitals or safer roads instead; yet no-one would claim we shouldn't be giving mathematical advice on that optimization.

Comment: [This question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/232220) is more directly related to life and death, about as directly as the present question. It has $150$ upvotes, no close votes and $17$ answers, one with $48$ upvotes. Should it be closed? If not, where is the difference?

Comment: joriki, the difference is that the programmer asking about ambulance schedules has some ability, however untrained, to translate correct mathematical observations to working code, and to discard that code if it fails simulation tests. This poor guy, whom I now believe to be legitimate, has no evident ability to correctly formulate his problem, nor to translate an answer into a better choice for his wife. His demands for a short and simple "answer" demonstrate that much.

Comment: I left a comment for Michael Hardy. He can cast the final vote to re-open and post an answer, if he sees some purpose to that. His Ph.D. is in statistics, although that does not guarantee he has tables of useful percentages in epidemiology.

Comment: For what it's worth, if "someone posts a question on how to optimize a process and save the government a lot of money," I would tell her to go away to hire a consultant.

Comment: The question was migrated to http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/45807/what-are-the-chances-my-wife-has-lupus  For the moment, there is also my question http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/45804/what-should-this-poor-guy-be-told with an excellent answer by an epidemiology guy, but the two questions will probably be folded together.

Comment: As Will noted, the question has been migrated. Should we edit this answer to include a note to that effect?

Comment: @Gerry: Yes, you might tell her to go away to hire a consultant, but you wouldn't vote for the question to be closed (and certainly not as "not constructive"). Of course you don't have to do unpaid work in such a case if you don't want to, and perhaps no-one wants to and then the question remains unanswered; but this entire site is about doing unpaid work for people, and such a question would be perfectly legitimate here.

Comment: @joriki, I don't mind doing unpaid work to help people learn mathematics. I do mind doing unpaid work to help people in private money-making enterprises. If they are going to make, or save, some money out of it, they should be willing to pay someone to help them.

Answer (score 3):

[RECLOSED] https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/327695/how-are-arrays-defined-with-gap

I really hope we can get past this anti-computer attitude.  If you don't want to do computational mathematics, that's fine, but please don't obstruct the participants who do.  Just ignore the tags if you don't like the questions.

> "We welcome questions about: ... Software that mathematicians use" - [FAQ](https://math.stackexchange.com/faq).

It's a reasonable question and the current answer lists only one way to create arrays in GAP.  There is still more to be learned.

---

For the same reason, I voted these to be reopened:

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/209266/how-do-i-break-magma

and

[REOPENED] [How does the function CycleIndex work in GAP? ( undocumented in GAP )](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/114577/how-does-the-function-cycleindex-work-in-gap-undocumented-in-gap)

Comment: Please be sure to follow your thread and update if the post has been reopened.

Answer (score 3):

[REOPENED] [Find $\det X$ if $8GX=XX^T$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/377162/which-xs-satisfies-the-equation-8gx-xxt#comment810427_377162) was closed as not a real question. I have edited it in light of comments by OP. I think it's a real question now (albeit an easy one, that I have answered in the comments).

Answer (score 3):

[REOPENED] [What explains this bizarre behavior?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/381193/)

I would like to see this question reopened. I believe it is a valid dynamical system question.

Comment: I voted to reopen. The OP noticed a very interesting effect that has puzzled a lot of people over the years.

Comment: @Grumpy: More accurately, *we* noticed an interesting effect, and we are *assuming* the OP noticed what we noticed. (And admittedly, *I* did *not* notice, because my eyes glazed over at the wall of digits and I didn't see the signs, although I did track the pattern of the decimal point)

Answer (score 3):

[REOPENED] (Thanks!)

I would like to see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/435025/462) reopened.

In fact, I do not understand why it was closed to begin with: The OP posted the question, and illustrated with examples what they meant. The question does not appear trivial, and its formulation takes some preliminaries, so it cannot just be stated in two lines.

In case the question is not clear, let me rephrase it as I did in the comments (but really, looking at the examples the OP provides may be better than chasing through the formalism here):

> Let $f,g$ be any linear functions from $\mathbb R$ to itself. If $h$ is a function obtained by composing $f,g$, in any order, say $h=j_1\circ j_2\circ\dots\circ j_n$, where each $j_i$ is $f$ or $g$; and $s=s_h$ is the fixed point of $h$, then we can associate a cycle to $h,s_h$ by considering the finite sequence 
>    $$ a_0=s_h,\quad a_1=j_n(s_h),\quad a_2=j_{n−1}\circ j_n(s_h),\dots,\quad a_n=j_1\circ \dots\circ j_n(s_h)=s_h. $$ 
>   (Note that the $a_i=a_i(h)$ depend on $h$.) Define $\mathrm{Sum}_g(h)$ as the sum of the $a_i$ with $i<n$ such that $j_{n−i}=g$.
>
> Now, let $S$ be obtained by composing $f,g$ in any order, and let $T$ be the result of composing in the reverse order, so if $S=j_1\circ\dots\circ j_n$, then $T=j_n\circ\dots \circ j_1$. The question is: **Is it true that we always have $\mathrm{Sum}_g(S)=\mathrm{Sum}_g(T)$? If so, how can we prove it?**

Answer (score 3):

[REOPENED] I have no doubt about what [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/446380/how-much-flower-we-need) is asking and have actually posted an answer in the form of a pair of comments. I’d prefer to give it a ‘real’ answer, however. I note that the question already has three votes to reopen.

Answer (score 3):

[REOPENED]

[This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/478684/solving-ode-with-negative-expansion-power-series) (A) was closed as a duplicate of [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/474959/solving-ode-with-negative-expansion-power-series) (B), but question B has no answers and question A already had one on closing.  Question A also had much more detail in the question itself.

I pointed out the first fact in the comments while close votes were being cast but it was closed anyway.

I think question A should be re-opened.  It might be worth considering whether B should be closed as a duplicate of A as well.

Comment: I agree with the general idea, but is it even true that (B) is a duplicate of (A)? In that, they have the same underlying questions but asking for different help with them? (Although I haven't read them in detail - they are long!)

Comment: @user1729 same here, I must admit.  I think A should be reopened at the very least.

Comment: Yes, I agree that (A) should be reopened.

Comment: You can reopen A, and close B as I am concerned (I asked them), the problem came because there was migration involved from physics SE.

Answer (score 3):

I would like to request that the following question be re-opened.

[Any two sets $Y$, $Z$ have the same cardinality $\iff$ there are injective functions $f: Y \rightarrow Z$ and $g: Z \rightarrow Y$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/498875/any-two-sets-y-z-have-the-same-cardinality-iff-there-are-injective-funct)

I has been closed as a duplicate. However, it is a "check my proof" question and so *cannot* be a duplicate. Yes, the underlying maths problems are the same, but the actual questions being asked are not.

Comment: It might not technically be a duplicate, but it already has an accepted answer, and anyone else searching for something related to this question will probably be better off redirected to the other question.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft True, but that isn't grounds for closing. That is grounds for linking to the other question in the comments.

Comment: While that might not be grounds for closing, I think it makes a decent case for not reopening, as this way the other question is placed at greater prominence for any later visitor.

Answer (score 3):

[REOPENED]

The question [Is there a continuous bijection between an interval and a square: $[0,1] \mapsto [0,1] \times [0,1]$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/510573/is-there-a-continuous-bijection-between-an-interval-and-a-square-0-1-mapsto) was closed as a duplicate of an older question [A bijective function between a square and its side](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/39079/a-bijective-function-between-a-square-and-its-side)

In my opinion, the newer question is better formulated (for example, the title corresponds to the body of the question) and it has more answers. So I suggest to reopen this question and close the older one as a duplicate instead.

(I have suggested this [in the comments](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/510573/is-there-a-continuous-bijection-between-an-interval-and-a-square-0-1-mapsto?noredirect=1#comment1095722_510573) and [in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/11466970#11466970) before the question was closed. This might be the reason that the older question has already received two closed votes. However, now that the newer one is already closed, it cannot be chosen as a target for closure of the older question as it would cause circular duplicate links.)

EDIT: Since the newer question is already reopened, [the older one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/39079/a-bijective-function-between-a-square-and-its-side) can now be closed as a duplicate.

**Edit 2 (LF)**: Older question is closed.

Comment: I agree with your proposal. However, I wonder if it would be better to make this into a proper meta question as opposed to leaving it here?

Comment: @user1729 It seems that combination meta + mentioning this in chat worked in this particular instance.

Comment: Sorry - I should have mentioned *why* I thought that. It was so that we could have a question which discussed this case and which could be used as precedent for future cases. Currently, the precedent is hidden away here and so isn't going to get the exposure needed for it to be a proper precedent.

Comment: @user1729 There already is a post about this: [Topics declared as duplicates in which order?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/10328/topics-declared-as-duplicates-in-which-order). (Although there are no answers there and that post seems to me to be about a particular instance, not about a general principle.) Feel free to make a post on meta about this problem, if you think it is needed. (I think it might be better to discuss the general principle on meta rather than some particular case of this problem.)

Comment: It's not a _huge_ discussion, but nonetheless the ultimate precedent is probably this mother-meta post: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/48838/146482

Comment: [Here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/6508/163)'s a related question on meta.math, though I'm not happy with the accepted answer...

Answer (score 3):

[REOPENED]

[A formula for the power sums: $1^n+2^n+\dotsc +k^n=\,$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/533772/1n2n-dots-kn) , from a user investigating that sum, presents a method that the OP tried to get the sum in closed form, observes that it doesn't work well, and then asks “are there other ways?”

The purportedly "duplicate" question [Finite Sum of Power?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/155166/finite-sum-of-power) also asks for the closed form, but not for a derivation, or for techniques to approach the problem, and the answer there doesn't give any.

(I voted to close the question, and on reflection, I regret my vote.  I have voted to reopen it. I will try to be more careful in the future.)

Comment: I've also done a comment from a bit of getting "sour" - but possibly "too much": occuring as a halo from some surrounding/related questions last time. I even overlooked (like you) that there was own work on the question - however I couldn't believe that someone would not look at wikipedia for something standard like this.(I think we should not attempt to rewrite wikipedia in MSE). So -maybe- my sour comment might have contributed to the "close question" call... Sorry for that.

Answer (score 3):

Please reopen https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/692746/intuition-if-f-differentiable-and-lim-x-to0-fx-l-then-f0-l

This question is for intuition only and no proofs. The other is for proofs. Ergo they aren't duplicates. The closers left no comments?

Comment: May be I'm wrong, but it seems to me the pleas to reopen work better, when they come from someone other than the original poster? I rather thought that was the whole point of having this thread.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen It works fine for the OP to post here if the question has either been edited to address whatever got it closed, or if the closure was based on a misunderstanding (I didn't check if either was the case here).

Comment: Ok. Thanks, @Tobias. In the present case the only editing done to the post after its closure was stylizing TeX.

Answer (score 3):

[REOPENED]

I think this post should be reopened: [Evaluate $\int\frac{\sqrt {25 - x^2}}{ x^4}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/722692/evaluate-int-frac-sqrt-25-x2-x4) (It already has 4 reopen votes, so only one vote is missing.)

It was closed as a duplicate of another post, but they are definitely not duplicates. (It seems that the problem might have been that the OP did not know how to make a post using TeX/MathJax.)

If course, if there is indeed a duplicate somewhere on the site or if you think that it should be closed for another reason, I do not object to closing the question. But at the moment it is closed for incorrect reasons.

Answer (score 3):

[REOPENED]

My question here was said to be too broad, so I tried to edit it with a more specific example: [How can you tell when you need to use the binomial coefficient for probabilities?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/726817/how-can-you-tell-when-you-need-to-use-the-binomial-coefficient-for-probabilities)

Answer (score 3):

This question:
[How come $1^{\infty}$ = undefined, while $2^{\infty} = \infty$ and $0^{\infty} = 0$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/785586/how-come-1-infty-undefined-while-2-infty-infty-and-0-infty) was closed as a duplicate of [Why is $1^{\infty}$ considered to be an indeterminate form](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/10490/why-is-1-infty-considered-to-be-an-indeterminate-form). I know that this is a tight one, but I do think that they are different in that one question asks why $1^{\infty}$ is an indeterminant form. The other asks shy $1^{\infty}$ is undefined. I think that this is slightly different so I request that the question be reopened.

Answer (score 3):

[REOPENED]

I'm not sure why [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/883279/5531) was put on hold for being "not about mathematics".  There seems to be an answerable question there (with a tentative answer of "yes, in a sense") with some leads by olive euler and Semiclassical in the comments.

Answer (score 3):

[REOPENED]

[Finding $\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\arctan\left(\sin x\right)dx$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1048045) was closed as a duplicate of [Evaluating a sum involving binomial coefficient in denominator](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/855517). While the statement of the closed question is mentioned in a later edit to the supposed original, the path leading from the integral to the sum is not part of the supposed original question.

Only half of the closed question is answered in the supposed original question. Therefore, I think that the question should be reopened.

Comment: It has 4 reopen votes, so you can cast one without using moderator powers.

Comment: @JonasMeyer: thanks. Done.

Answer (score 2):

[REOPENED. I cast the binding fourth vote on behalf of myself and Bill Dubuque]

This question: [Prove $f(S \cap T) \subseteq f(S) \cap f(T)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/231145/prove-fs-cap-t-subseteq-fs-cap-ft#question) was voted to be closed as a duplicate of [Is this a valid proof of $f(S \cap T) \subseteq f(S) \cap f(T)$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/228613/is-this-a-valid-proof-of-fs-cap-t-subseteq-fs-cap-ft)

However, the question asked actually was different. The latter asks for the readers to check whether the OP gave a valid proof (he didn't, and counterexamples were given as answers). The former asks for a proof. The closest answer we have on the *latter* to this question is [this sketch of a proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/228625/1543). So I don't really think the two are exact duplicates of each other.

(The other proposed duplicate target is a mistake, as noted in the comments.)

Comment: I agree, since your vote and mine bring the count to 5, you should feel welcome to reopen it.

Answer (score 2):

[REOPENED] I would like the following:
[is $0.\overline{99}$ the same as $\lim_{x \to 1} x$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/237571/is-0-overline99-the-same-as-lim-x-to-1-x)

to be reopened. The question is currently closed as a duplicate of [Is it true that $0.999999999\ldots = 1$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/11/does-99999-1).

While I agree that at the base is indeed that $0.\overline{9}$ = 1, but the OP actually says that he/she knows the proof of this. It seems like the question is more about the confusion about the function that is introduced in the question. While the question might not be worded perfectly, I don't think that it should be closed.

Answer (score 2):

[Re-closed as duplicate about Cartesian to Polar change of variables. See [comment below](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/6424/requests-for-reopen-votes?page=2&tab=active#comment23799_6699).]

I propose that we should reopen [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/247644/show-that-int-limits-infty-infty-mathbbe-x2-mathrmdx) question, and posted my reason in the comments.

It was closed as an exact duplicate of a thread asking how to evaluate a Gaussian integral.  But actually, the question was why, when one converts from Cartesian to polar coordinates, $dx\,dy$ gets replaced by $r\,dr\,d\theta$.  That's not what the other question was about.  There are other ways to evaluate the Gaussian integral than by polar coordinates, and those other ways would be appropriate answers to that older question, but not to this one.  In some ways, the presence of a Gaussian integral in this question is incidental.  It was really only the particular occasion for the question about polar coordinates.

Comment: It is actually a duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/37044/explain-iint-mathrm-dx-mathrm-dy-iint-r-mathrm-d-alpha-mathrm-dr

Answer (score 2):

[REOPENED]The question [A question about series with a strange property.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/269961/a-question-about-a-series-with-a-strange-property#question) should be re-opened. As the OP [remarked](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/269961/a-question-about-a-series-with-a-strange-property#comment590674_269961) the supposed duplicate does not actually answer the question posed.

(More details: the supposed duplicate has two questions in it. One without sign restrictions. The other restricting to positive series. An answer was given and accepted for the latter. But no answer was given for the former. The new question explicitly asks for the former.)

Answer (score 2):

[REOPENED] I would like to see [**this post**](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/268726/9003) reopened.

It is clear that it generated *a lot of thought about relations*, their properties, etc. Many questions of this nature are posted to this site, and are not closed as "non-constructive."  Many students are very interested in *"real-life" applications/interpretations* of the math they are learning. ${}$

Comment: I don't think this post should be re-opened, although I agree that "non-constructive" might be off-putting. I think that the question generated a lot of buzz, which is good, but when you have several repeated answers and deletions it's time to close down. If we had "no longer relevant" as a closing reason I would vote that.

Comment: @Asaf I'd suggest protecting the question, if reopened. I do understand your point, and I think if the closure reason could be customized by a moderator to indicate what you suggest, I'd be okay with that.

Comment: I agree and have also voted to reopen. I think protecting the question is more appropriate.

Comment: I have to say that I also agree with Asaf. "non-constructive" portrays an inaccurate perspective on what is being meant; it is clear that the question is simply no longer relevant. Although, there's a possibility that a user could input a very interesting answer and I am not entirely sure why this should not occur. I do not fully understand the things between the lines of the FAQ and rules of the site, though! I have not voted to reopen as I do not fully comprehend the critique of those who voted to close and I'd rather not step on any toes.

Answer (score 2):

[REOPENED] [This question about a set containing itself](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/271063/856) was closed as "not a real question", with both posted answers interpreting it as a tautology that $X \subseteq X$. However, the question is really about the paradox $X \in X$; [the word *contains* can have another meaning as $\ni$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/184093/856), and the question actually mentions the axiom of regularity! Granted, it's not a *great* question, and is easily resolved by prodding the asker about the definition of set complement, but that doesn't make it "not a real question".

Answer (score 2):

[REOPENED] Please reopen [From a mathematician's point of view, what is the purpose of '$dx$' in $\int f(x)\ dx$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/282056/from-a-mathematicians-point-of-view-what-is-the-purpose-of-dx-in-int-fx). I had written out  (what I thought of as) a nice answer, then just before trying to post it, it was closed as a duplicate of [What is $dx$ in integration?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/200393/what-is-dx-in-integration).

However, this question is different since it deals with the difference in the way physicists and mathematicians understand $dx$ (something that my answer was going to address).

Comment: Do you mean http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/282056/from-a-mathematicians-point-of-view-what-is-the-purpose-of-dx-in-int-fx?

Comment: @AsafKaragila: Yes, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

[REOPENED] In [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/359778), the OP has edited to point out why the question isn't a duplicate. Please reopen.

Answer (score 2):

[REOPENED] I would like to see [How to prove the earning decomposition of 2 people in mediocristan and extremistan?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/332883/how-to-prove-the-earning-decomposition-of-2-people-in-mediocristan-and-extremist) reopened. Please note that a highly reputed user has added a comment saying: "I would like to reopen and answer."

Answer (score 2):

[REOPENED]

The question [Probability of random integer's digits summing to 12](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/372624/probability-of-random-integers-digits-summing-to-12) was recently closed despite several well-supported requests in the comments that it not be closed (two of the close votes came after these comments were posted) and despite that it was a legitimate question, well-posed, clear, and attracted several constructive answers.

Answer (score 2):

[REOPENED]  [This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/373708/23500) was closed as a duplicate (by a single binding moderator vote). However, the question is certainly not a duplicate of the linked question, since the author is asking additionally a more general question, namely "What are those number theoretic situations?" (where the unit group is cyclic). This is an interesting question that is not addressed at all in the proposed duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

[REOPENED] [This question][1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/383571/rational-trigonometric-integral#383571) was closed as a duplicate. It's not a duplicate for two reasons. The major reason is that the question was not about how to solve the problem but about where the OP's own calculations went wrong. The minor reason is that the other question is more general and the generality requires more complicated answers that make it more difficult to find the error in the present simpler calculations. Please reopen.

Answer (score 2):

[REOPENED] (Thanks. That was fast!)

This [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/375260/462) was closed, I just found out, because it came as part of a contest, whose deadline has passed. Now that the deadline is behind us, I think it deserves to be reopened, and it may receive interesting answers.

There is also a nice answer that was deleted for this reason, and I believe it should be undeleted as well.

(Related to this: It would be nice if, in case this happens again, all people who posted answers are notified. As I said, I just noticed today, by coincidence, that the question was part of a contest, was closed, and an answer was deleted. A comment informing me would have been appreciated. I imagine other people in similar situations would appreciate such courtesy as well.)

Answer (score 2):

[REOPENED] (Tons of thanks!)

My question ["How to show the relation $<$ is not definable in $(\Bbb N; 0, \operatorname {S})$ by quantifier elimination?"](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/408867/how-to-show-the-relation-is-not-definable-in-bbb-n-0-operatorname-s) is closed as duplicate.

The fault is on my side, since I weren't aware of the two duplicate questions on this site and failed to add the link to stress the difference between my difficulty and the former OP's.  In particular,the thing I want to know is how to show that by quantifier elimination, while the existing answers are both using automorphism.

Now I have edited the question accordingly. Could you please vote to reopen the question?

Answer (score 2):

[REOPENED] I voted to close [Books to understand the construction of all groups of a specific order](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/422363/books-to-understand-the-construction-of-all-groups-of-a-specific-order) because the OP originally gave a confused presentation.  However @JackSchmidt has provided a nicely reworded version, and I have voted to reopen.

Answer (score 2):

[REOPENED] [This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/431476/43351) was closed, (I suspect) because it had unprocessed TeX. The question was improved afterwards, and does not deserve to be closed anymore.

Answer (score 2):

[REOPENED] I would like to see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/428499/non-symmetric-at-a) re-opened. I believe it was closed because the OP was asking a question which showed a fundamental miss-understanding. Such a question should receive attention, and the OP should be helped. Closing it is, well, pointless.

(Also, if you dig into the closing, you will see that it is closed not because it has five votes to close but because a moderator cast the fourth vote and a moderator's vote is binding (the question is closed immediately). According to the [Review](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/close/78185), there were three votes to leave open, two to close.)

Comment: Could the down-voter please tell me their thoughts? I am interested in what you think! Make me change my opinion...

Answer (score 2):

[Re-opened]

[This meta question](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/10160/43351) was closed even after the following comment by *anorton*:

> @Closevoters: This is not a duplicate of the [suggested duplicate.](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/10133). That question is talking about a moderator's action, this one is talking about a normal user's action.

which hits the nail on the head.

Answer (score 2):

[Re-opened]

[Generalizations of fitting subgroup](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/423486/generalizations-of-fitting-subgroup) was closed because it was incredibly unclear what was being asked. The original poster clarified the question and it is now clear what is being asked.

I am composing a little essay with references on them as I've been studying generalizations of Fitting subgroups for a while now.

Comment: I disagree that it was *incredibly* unclear. It was only unclear because noone here had come across the notation before (as is, of course, the way with notation). Although it would have been helpful if he had responded to your comment earlier! Anyway, moot point, and your answer is excellent so +1.

Answer (score 2):

[Now deleted]

I would like to see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/445239/real-world-applications-of-the-fibonacci-series) big-list question re-opened. It is on the "Real-world applications of the Fibonacci Series". As I said in the comments, I do not think that this question should be closed. There is a [big-list] tag for a reason. The tag's wiki says "Please do not ask too many of these" not "Do not ever ask these".

Also, I believe that wondering about the applications of different aspects of mathematics is a worthwhile thing to do! If you ever have to write a fellowship application, then it is doubly worthwhile! However, the comments seem to be saying "How *dare* you ask about applications of mathematics! We do not care about such trifles here!"

I would be grateful if those who want to keep the question closed could comment here on *why* they have this opinion. You have heard my view, and I am interested in hearing yours.

Comment: @Downvoter: When I wrote "I would be grateful if those who want to keep the question closed could comment here on why they have this opinion", I was talking to you...

Comment: Sorry I just saw this. I think the question should remain closed until the OP has suitably narrowed the question down (or split in to distinct posts) to something which can be answered in a few paragraphs. As it stands, there are two 'big list' questions only tangentially related to each other, and another question which could receive some great attention as a history of maths questions if posted separately. I've added a comment to the same affect on the question.

Answer (score 2):

[REOPENED] [This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/454037/ratio-and-propotion) was put on hold as unclear. It seems perfectly clear to me, and I’ve just given an answer in the comments.

Comment: The answer you gave seems however incorrect. (See main for details.)

Comment: @quid: It is entirely correct. You’ve misunderstood the question.

Comment: Sorry for commenting here too (likely I should only have written one comment initially), but now I feel the need to clarify also here that the problem was not me misunderstanding the question. More pertinent to the meta discussion, I might however add that the problem indeed seems understandable as written. Whether or not it is up to the standards of this site is unknown to me (not being very familiar with them).

Answer (score 2):

[REOPENED]

I'd like to see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/533051/28900) reopened. Initially, the OP was attempting to prove the (false) statement that an infinite Hausdorff space has infinitely-many isolated points, but altered the question after this was pointed out. It now asks the much more interesting question as to whether every Hausdorff space has an infinite subspace, all of whose points are isolated, based on the example of $\Bbb N$ in $\Bbb R$.

Comment: But the new version still has a trivial counterexample.

Comment: I have fixed it (if I correctly figured out what you meant).

Comment: However, if there is still a (trivial) counterexample, @Tobias, please post it as an answer, and resolve the issue completely and finally.

Comment: I only meant the finite one. I have not thought further about the infinite one (but since no example pops to mind, I find that it is probably a worthwhile question, even if a trivial counterexample turns out to exist).

Answer (score 2):

[REOPENED]

I would like [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/550259/show-that-x-can-be-imbedded-in-mathbbrn-for-some-positive-integer-n#550347) reopened. Closing it because the OP didn't state anything beyond the bare question is a little harsh, and the question is interesting.

EDIT: Paul Siegel's answer has been accepted with 3 upvotes. That seems to indicate that reopening is appropriate.

Comment: Why not wait that the OP "add(s) in what (they) have tried and where (they) came across", as was suggested to the OP in a detailed comment?

Comment: @Did: because closing it seems like a heavy-handed way to get the OP to respond. The detailed comment that was left was more than sufficient.

Comment: The problem is indeed interesting, and currently has a solution that could use checking (I fixed some of the problems, I think, but I don't know if I did so correctly). I don't know, however, about the bad precedent that could set....

Comment: @dfeuer: There are plenty of questions where the OP only states the problem which have not been closed. Closing this questions strikes me as absurdly harsh.

Comment: Of course the best turn of events would be if the OP edits.

Comment: @GrumpyParsnip Two weeks later... and in view of the subsequent (or lack of) events, do you still hold the same view?

Comment: @Did: maybe a good course of action would be to reopen - and *wiki-fy* - the question. Then the OP doesn't get any reputation (and the thought that they did anything *right...*), but the community still gets the benefit of having answers to the question. Granted, there are already answers...

Comment: @Did: I still think it deserves to be reopened, even if it has been abandoned by the OP. It's the question itself that is interesting, not the person behind it.

Comment: It's really not clear to me how one goes about drawing enough attention to reopen.

Comment: @dfeuer: I edited the answer to bump it to the forefront.

Comment: @dfeuer: thanks for fixing my comment.

Answer (score 2):

[REOPENED]

[This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/589626/linear-algebra-matrix-and-determinant) is typical basic linear algebra homework, directly pasted from the textbook. So it sure looks bad at first.

But read until the end... the OP actually proposed answers for every question and is simply asking for confirmation. So s/he probably did not get that from an answer key.

This certainly includes the OP's attempts to solve the problem, and I don't understand why it was closed. At least not for the specific reason which is mentioned. What is unclear here for sure is the message sent to the OP...

Answer (score 2):

[REOPENED] Thanks.

[This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/599999/38053) has been put on hold as off-topic. I would like to see this reopened because:

1 - Unless I missed something, this is not exactly an easy question. If it is, anyway, I would really like to see easier solutions. This was not a routine reasoning for me, so if I made mistakes, I would really like interested people to point them out.

2 - For sure, it is a natural one for which the context had been provided by the OP: s/he mentioned Carleman's and Hardy's inequality, and this is the $p=-1$ case of the latter which is known to hold for $p>1$ when you read the wikipedia entry, for instance.

3 - Although I expect an OP to share some thoughts/efforts, on a trivial/standard question, I don't care if the OP does not add "I tried this (whatever) and it did not work, can you help me please?" on a harder question.

4 - This is the question I've been the most interested in for quite some time. I did not even know about Carleman's and Hardy's inequality: so I've learned something and I have had a lot of fun looking for the answers. Exactly what I am here for.

5 - I would enjoy seeing other answers with different approaches.

6 - I recall this OP had already asked several interesting nontrivial complex analysis questions from a book s/he was reading. Please let us not shy this user away from asking questions.

Answer (score 2):

[REOPENED]

The author of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/611388/5531) added the requested details before the last "no context" vote was cast, so the question should be reopened.

Answer (score 2):

[REOPENED]

[This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/616672/242) was closed as a duplicate, but the question specifically asks not for a proof (which the OP knows) but, instead, for some intuition behind successful strategies for constructing such proofs  - something that is not addressed at all in the proposed duplicate. Probably there is a good chance of further helpful answers appearing if it is reopened.

Answer (score 2):

reopened

[This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/619731/221) was closed.  It seems to have been edited in the meantime, and seems reasonable to me at this point.

I gave a partial answer in a comment, but it would be more convenient for everyone if it could be reopened and answered properly (with hints, further explanation,
whatever people find appropriate).

Answer (score 2):

[REOPENED]

In my relatively expert opinion [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/621101/11619) is perfectly clear. Yet it was put on hold as *unclear what you are asking*. The OP also has put a rather non-trivial amount of effort into understanding the question given that they say to have implemented the usual Viterbi decoding algorithm. Admittedly the OP has built a bit of a history in asking coding theoretical questions that actually are unclear and/or show very little effort. This question is not one of those. I will answer it in a comment (it has a very quick answer), and let anyone else take a first bite at answering. But keeping this on hold sends IMHO a wrong signal.

Answer (score 2):

[REOPENED; thank you]

[Ambiguity in the Natural Numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/637349/ambiguity-in-the-natural-numbers) asks what seems to me to be a very clear and specific question about whether two different axiomatizations of the natural numbers can contradict one another. This has been a serious research subject in the past, and it admits a positive answer, which Henning Makholm and I independently wrote.

It was closed as "unclear", but I disagree.

Answer (score 2):

[REOPENED]

Please reopen [Algebraically compute $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin x}{x}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/628252/3736) which was closed as a duplicate of [How to prove that $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin x}{x}=1$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/75130/3736).  The latter explicitly asks for a geometric solution, while the former explicitly asks for a solution that uses as little geometry as possible.  My own reopen vote has already expired, as have two others.

Comment: It is not a duplicate, but it qualifies for "unclear what you are asking", if geometric reasoning and series are both unwelcome.

Comment: @Phira: the OP clarified that he wants to minimize the amount of geometry used, even if eliminating it entirely is not possible.  The meta question is whether it is better to close such a question or to allow people to provide answers either explaining the impossibility or exploring the extent to which the use of geometry can be reduced or eliminated.  My own view is that there are many different ways to define the sine function; in some definitions, no geometry is needed to prove the statement, even though that definition might have  a geometric interpretation or inspiration.

Answer (score 2):

[REOPENED. Thank you.]

Will you please to reopen [Infer distance from a point to a line, from the distance from a point to a plane [Stewart P793 12.4.44]](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/650682/infer-distance-from-a-point-to-a-line-from-the-distance-from-a-point-to-a-plane)?

My question is tendered at the bottom of my question and there are no comments on why it is avowedly "unclear." I've made an ancillary edit that should only clarify the OP.

Comment: I gave some spacing between the [REOPENED] part to the text, so it'll be clearer that it's been reopened.

Answer (score 2):

Please re-open https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/685061/undefinably-large-algebra . It has been substantially revised and should be sufficiently clear at this point. Also, note that you can address the question without addressing my semi-formalization of a hopeful answer. Suggestions for helping the question be re-opened can be put here: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/12825/working-towards-re-opening-undefinably-large-algebra?noredirect=1#comment50240_12825

Answer (score 2):

Please reopen https://math.stackexchange.com/q/690129/85079 please.

The closers didn't comment on what 'missing context or other details' they were vexed about. I wrote 'thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it'?

Comment: Indeed, the close reason seems strange. That one is "unclear what you are asking" just like the other two you have asked about here.

Answer (score 2):

Please reopen https://math.stackexchange.com/q/679700/85079.

My question is long but I put my questions in the gray shaded boxes. Questions are numbered too and spaced. Ergo it should not be 'unclear what you're asking.' None of the closers commented?

Comment: Did you see where it said, "Beware that "short" requests such as "request reopening of <link>" may be automatically converted to comments by the SE software, so you will need to say more, such as why you think that the question should be reopened.

"Please do not use this thread to engage in debates on contentious matters (e.g. reasons for closure)."

Comment: @GerryMyerson: thanks. did the website convert this to a comment? i didn't know. i wrote about the numbering too. is it enough now? i don't want to essay too much.

Answer (score 2):

Please reopen https://math.stackexchange.com/q/678715/85079 please.

My question is long but I put my questions in the gray shaded boxes. Questions are numbered too and spaced. Ergo it should not be 'unclear what you're asking.' None of the closers commented?

Comment: Did you see where it said, "Beware that "short" requests such as "request reopening of <link>" may be automatically converted to comments by the SE software, so you will need to say more, such as why you think that the question should be reopened.

"Please do not use this thread to engage in debates on contentious matters (e.g. reasons for closure)."

Comment: The question has since been automatically deleted by the Community user.

Comment: @T.Bongers And, worse, 10K users cannot vote to undelete since a Community bot deletion counts as moderation deletions. Bots should not be considered smarter than users regarding such.

Comment: @BillDubuque: Dear Bill, A revised version of the question has since been posted (by the same OP), but in a Catch-22-like situation, has been closed essentially for being a duplicate of this (now deleted) question.  I have voted to reopen the new question; maybe you would like to as well, since the old question seems irretrievable? Regards,

Comment: @MattE Thanks for the notice. I too voted to reopen [the newer version.](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/776899/242) I find it very disturbing that some users are not only voting to close these questions, but also to *delete* them (e.g. this newer one). These questions show genuine concern about understanding the essence of proofs. Yet questions that don't, but merely have random content injected in order to meet the "show effort" constraint remain opened and rewarded by the same users. What a sad state of affairs.

Answer (score 2):

[REOPENED]

[Counting Shaded Squares](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/744161/counting-shaded-squares) was closed as "missing context or other details". It is a perfectly clear and straightforward question about combinatorics: how many ways are there to color exactly two squares in an $n×n$ array.  Marko Riedel and I each had no trouble answering it.

(I voted to close, not as "missing context" but as a duplicate of [how many unique patterns exist for a NxN grid](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/570003/how-many-unique-patterns-exist-for-a-nxn-grid) .  But on review I see that the two questions are different.)

Answer (score 2):

[REOPENED]

[Becoming Better at Math](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/766657/12952) was closed on the grounds of being primarily opinion-based.  It is community wiki with [soft-question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/soft-question) and [advice](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/advice) tags.  Though there are many possible answers (hence the CW), I do not find the question to be opinion based, as it is a call for guidance from experienced mathematics students, who in general do not disagree about most fundamental aspects of learning mathematics. (In other words, though opinion-based answers to this questions may exist, certainly not all answers are opinion-based.)  This question could serve as a useful collection of practical advice specifically aimed at high school aged students preparing to major in math in college.

Comment: Alexander, there are four votes at the moment. So I suppose that if you cast the fifth it won't be an abuse of the mod powers.

Comment: Thanks, @Asaf. Even so, since I have an answer on that question, I would prefer to wait for the final vote from someone else.

Answer (score 2):

[REOPENED]

This question, [Number of solutions of equation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/774218/number-of-solutions-of-equation), asks a perfectly straightforward question of combinatorics. It has attracted three answers, including a really impressive one from Marko Riedel using multiset cycle indices.

Answer (score 2):

[REOPENED]

My query [Applications of Countable Infinite Sets and Power Sets](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/832784/applications-of-countable-infinite-sets-and-power-sets) was put on-hold as it was not clear. I have edited it and hope it is a little better now. I am new to this forum and so if it still not fine then I would be glad if anyone could suggest how to make it fit. Otherwise, I would request that it is kindly re-opened so that I may get some answers.

Answer (score 2):

[REOPENED]

This question seems crystal-clear despite the fact that the poster's command of English is weak.

[Ordered field with nested intervals axiom without Archimedean axiom](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/870052/ordered-field-with-nested-intervals-princepe-without-archimed-princepe)

Answer (score 2):

[REOPENED, RECLOSED, REOPENED]

I believe that [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/882256/why-does-the-imaginary-number-i-satisfy-i-times-0-0) should be reopened. It is asking why $i\times 0=0$, but has been closed as "unclear what you are asking". I do not see why this is unclear: it is very clear! Moreover, $i\times0=0$ is a theorem, but the OP thinks it is assumed - this is a chance to help someone! Why waste the chance by closing the question...?

Comment: "i×0=0 is a theorem" Hmmmm... :-)

Comment: @Did Well, it isn't an axiom! :-)

Comment: @user1729: So it's just a conjecture? :-)

Answer (score 2):

[REOPENED]

I believe that [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/298011/find-a-translation-that-fixes-y-cos-x) should be reopened. It was closed as "unclear", but it *is* clear (and further clarity can be found in the comments below the question).

Comment: Would the downvoter care to comment? Are you saying it *is* unclear?

Answer (score 2):

[REOPENED; RECLOSED (AS A DUPLICATE)]

I would like to reopen [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/891006/14972), so that it may be reclosed as an appropriate duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

[Undeleted]

Please vote for undelete [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/891110/a-naive-question-on-castelnuovo-mumford-regularity/891282#891282).

It asks for an important property of Castelnuovo-Mumford regularity, and the answer I've posted there could be useful for future readers.

Thanks.

Comment: Voted to undelete. Wonder what prompted the OP to delete in the first place?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Thanks. I think the OP has considered the question trivial (although he asked for the wrong inequality).

Comment: FYI, @user26857, it's undeleted now.

Comment: @DanielFischer Thank you all.

Answer (score 2):

[RE-OPENED]

I edited [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/915909/make-complete-piece-of-number) to make it clearer. OP has commented that my edit is acceptable. I would like to encourage re-opening of the question.

Comment: Can you perhaps edit the title as well? I voted to close in its original form (although the edit history implies otherwise!). After a cursory glance, it looks much improved. However, the title just looks like a random collection of words! If you improve it so that I have an idea of what the post is about without having to read it all (it is rather long!) then I will vote to reopen.

Comment: @user, I will edit the title. Meanwhile, in reading the body, you can skip all the way down to where it says EDIT.

Comment: Gotcha! Isn't the required algorithm simply "division" though? I'll comment on the main question...

Comment: @user, I don't think it's just division. If you look at the example, where you want to make 10 from 3s and 2s, dividing 10 by 3 gives 3, but you can't use 3 3s since you don't have any 1s. You have to use 2 3s and 2 2s.

Comment: Do you want to make that a comment to the main question? Better to discuss the actual question there, and the reopening here. (Although I will admit that I haven't actually read the whole post, just your edit!)

Answer (score 2):

[REOPENED, RECLOSED]

I think that [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/950520/math-problem-is-xyz-is-divisibleby-xyz) should be reopened so that it can be reclosed as "off-topic". It's clear what's being asked, but it's a PSQ with no input whatsoever. I'm asking because of [this other question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/950551/prove-that-x-y-z-is-divisible-by-xyz) complaining that it was closed with the "unclear" reason.

Comment: Perhaps it can be reclosed as duplicate.

Comment: How can both questions be off-topic? According to this page, http://math.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer , you can ask and answer your own question if you know the answer and would like to document the knowledge. Since it wasn't possible to answer the other question, which had been put on hold, I did the only thing possible to document the knowledge and invite other answers.

Comment: @user179549 I actually didn't realize that you had self-answered your question. Closing the other as a duplicate (or merging, since they are literally the same question) seems more appropriate then. Still, I don't think what you did was completely OK, but that's a different discussion that I'm not willing to have now.

Comment: I don't appreciate that you're telling me what I did wasn't okay, but at the same time, you don't want to say why and don't want to discuss it.

Comment: @user179549 Okay, let me explain then. The other question was in the process of being reopened; once it would have been reopened, you could have answered it. On the other hand, it was of abysmal quality: it was a PSQ with no input at all, never even mind the formatting problems. In fact, it was probably someone trying to make us do his homework. Just for that, it should have been closed as off-topic. If you really wanted to see this question have an answer, improving it (by adding motivation etc) was IMO the best course of action. Then it would have been reopened and would have stayed open.

Comment: How was I supposed to know it was in the process of being reopened? As far as I could tell when I posted my question, nothing had changed or would change. And I couldn't have edited Abdo's question to provide motivation either, since I didn't know his motivation. Most of your comments seem directed at the OP's perceived lack of effort rather than the real purpose of the site, which is to document knowledge.

Comment: @user179549 I do not mean to be rude, but you're an unregistered user who has been a member for less than a day. I suggest that you familiarize yourself with the website before claiming you know its "real purpose". This argument we're having has been played out dozens of times on meta. [This should be a good starting point](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=homework) (and [this proposal](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9201/proposal-discourage-questions-that-are-nothing-besides-a-problem-statement) is of most interest, I think).

Comment: Najib, I don't see anything there that applies to my asking and answering the question. Could you please clarify whether you're saying that if the question had been closed as you said it should have, it would have been inappropriate for me to ask and answer the question?

Comment: @user179549 Is it appropriate to ask again a question that was already asked and had an answer, regardless of whether it was closed? The answer is no. Either you can ask the new question in a way that makes it fit for the website (ie. with motivation etc), and then you can just edit the old question and it will be reopened, or you can't, in which case you shouldn't ask that question altogether.

Comment: The two posts have now been merged.

Comment: For reference: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/16930/18398

Answer (score 2):

[UNDELETED]

This [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/952223/distribution-of-the-rsa-numbers) was recently deleted by the Community user. It has 2 answers, both voted better than +5, both with mathematical content I think benefitting the site. Please consider voting to undelete.

Answer (score 2):

[UNDELETED]

[How to switch to a Laurent series' next convergence ring?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/503548/how-to-switch-to-a-laurent-series-next-convergence-ring)

I don't even know for sure how/why it was deleted, though I assume it's an automatism. Not having found any specific information, I ask [a meta question](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/16998/how-why-did-community-delete-a-question-and-how-to-prevent-it)

Answer (score 2):

[Undeleted]

[This user](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/157791/ben-lim) posted few hours ago [a question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/975093/do-we-have-dim-a-max-mathfrakp-operatornameht-mathfrakp-0) which I've answered, but he deleted this soon after posting my answer. Because I think that question can be helpful for other users, I'm asking for undelete it.

Answer (score 2):

[(DELETED, UNDELETED)^2, DELETED]

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1022883/let-xn-be-a-bounded-but-not-convergent-sequence-prove-that-xn-has-two-subse was recently deleted.

The original question suffered from a lack of context. The poster supplied context *before* the question was closed (unfortunately, in the form of an answer, rather than as an edit), but the final vote(s) to close were cast anyway. Then people started voting down the (good) answers that had been posted, presumably to make it easier to delete the question, so the content of the answers is gone now, as well.

I'd like to see the question undeleted.

I'd also like to see people stop voting down good answers, but it seems that is asking for too much.

Comment: Voted to reopen the current version. I didn't downvote those answers, but if they arrived when the question was very bad I understand the reason. That is the only way to try and pass the message.

Comment: If it is opened it can be linked to a couple of duplicates provided in the comments.

Comment: Oops! I had missed those. Thanks for pointing them out, @Jonas. Can close it as a dup instead :-/

Comment: I've just cast the final vote for undeletion; it's better to leave duplicates undeleted (yet linked) for searching.

Comment: @anorton Not when the texts of the questions are identical. That's just duplication of content.

Comment: (Especially when the only existing answer is an extremely cryptic hint -- there is still much work to do after using that hint)

Comment: @Najib, there are *four* answers to that question, but three of them were subject to downvoting attacks and deleted. Would you be OK with keeping the question undeleted, if the three deleted answers were undeleted as well?

Comment: There are already two questions, one of them with the exact same text for the question (so the "google" argument doesn't hold). The other questions already mention Bolzano-Weierstrass in the question text. They both have upvoted, undeleted answers. Meanwhile this question only *had* one undeleted answer, heavily downvoted. If it's undeleted it should be closed as a dup anyway. What do you want, exactly? Or better, why do you want this question undeleted so bad?

Comment: What I want is for the question to be undeleted, reopened, closed as a duplicate, and its answers undeleted and merged into the other question, with the malicious downvotes reversed, and the malicious downvoters suspended. That's not asking much, is it?

Comment: The first part of your request seems reasonable; the reversion of the down-votes, however, not so much, and the request for suspension is definitely not reasonable.

Comment: "A moderator has deleted this post and it cannot be undeleted"

Comment: @Gerry Re: "malicious downvoters suspended" Hear, hear! I'd expand that to malicious deleters too.

Comment: @Martin, thanks. I suppose that what one moderator has deleted, another moderator can undelete?

Comment: Please, [see this.](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/18926/regarding-the-closure-and-deletion-of-two-particular-posts). Regards,

Comment: @Pedro It would help to be more informative, e.g. "Please see this meta thread which explains why I unilaterally deleted this question" vs. "please see this".

Answer (score 2):

[UNDELETED, then DELETED again by Community, UNDELETED]

Please vote for undelete [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1046622/prove-that-if-phim-rightarrow-prod-i-in-i-m-m-i-is-surjective-then-m-m-j/1046628#1046628).

I've posted an answer and a mathematical comment there which I think can be useful to other users.

Moreover, this should be considered as a kind of warning to that user (who posted his first question on M.SE today) that this is not the way M.SE is working: posting a question, get an answer, then delete the question.

Thanks.

Comment: The number of drive-by shooters is on the increase. I've seen too many lately, too. Such encounters always make me feel ill. One more reason to vote in favor of obligatory registration.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen In this case happened something I've never seen: the user deleted the question, but also deleted his account!

Comment: I'm afraid I've seen that before, too.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen In this case, registering the account was necessary to have the ability to delete the question. Unregistered users cannot delete.

Comment: @Jyrki: All the more reason to heed to Pete L. Clark's call to "Vote early, vote often" from way back.

Comment: I support that spirit, @Asaf. But when the question looks like a copy/pasted HW problem I want to engage the asker first. The last time I did that it backfired. I gave a hint, then started typing in my welcoming speech, explaining what was problematic about the question. After the first such comment, the OP thanked for the comments, deleted the question and the account. I was like "WTF?". I'm sure we've all seen worse. Many of them won't post that thank you comment :-/

Answer (score 2):

[REOPENED]

The question [Which of the following abelian groups are cyclic groups?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1064943/which-of-the-following-abelian-groups-are-cyclic-groups) just got closed.

It is not quite clear to me why, since the OP gave some indication of their progress.
Indeed, I first voted to close myself but took it back when noticing this. 
This was even moved from a comment to the body (by me) at 1 or 2 votes only.

Meanwhile the question got also a pretty good answer, which actually explains something while not solving the problem completely.

Comment: I wonder if the reopen queue would have taken care of this one, assuming you voted to reopen.

Comment: Obviously, I did vote to reopen. However, I thought I'd give this explanation, since *nothing on the post changed* relative to the version that was closed (excepting  the first one or two votes). Thus,  there was  no good reason  to believe that without explanation the decision would change.

Comment: (It seems obvious, but doesn't always happen that those with 3K+ who express displeasure with a question's closing vote to reopen.)  I would be optimistic; it wouldn't just be the same people reviewing.  All 3 reopen votes that didn't come from you or me came through the reopen review queue.  Maybe those three also saw this post, so I'm not sure of the significance of that.

Comment: It is likely true that I could have waited for a while, before posting here. However, in principle, I would also have been open to the option that somebody explains why they think it should still stay closed here; while I am quite versed in the mechanics of the site, I might not fully understand the nuances of some views around "PSQ."  Furthermore, this question seemed like good showcase of certain type of unfolding of events; so I meant to record it. Indeed, I even thought about posting a question proper, but then decided for posting here as a middle ground.

Answer (score 2):

[Undeleted]

Consider undeleting [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1081881/logical-proof-gone-wrong) question for the reason that the OP deleted out of frustration (check the comments) and it's a perfectly good question with the exception of the missing quantifiers, but this is something which the OP is lacking in knowledge and can easily be addressed.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1081845

Comment: There aren't even downvotes on the post, I don't know why he deleted it...

Comment: @Najib: I think there was one downvote when I looked earlier (after seeing this post).  I don't know how it was possible for the downvote to go away.

Comment: @Jonas Um, in this case I guess maybe a serial downvoter? [And indeed, some serial downvoting was reversed](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/131263/barak-manos?tab=reputation) today.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi There was a down vote before.

Comment: Thank you everyone for the undeletion.

Answer (score 1):

[REOPENED]  I would like to see

[Properties of the number 50](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/225518/properties-of-the-number-50)

reopens.

With $13$ upvotes it is clear that there are members of th comunity that find it to be interesting, and I recall such a question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/168485) (that asked for integrals and etc' with the value being someones age was not closed).

Comment: Compare the two questions though: Answers to "integrals that evaluate to 59" are interesting maths puzzles.  Answers to "what's interesting about 50" are trivia (to illustrate, the top-ranked answer at the moment is on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/50_(number))).

Comment: I definitely think that such questions should be closed.  By leaving it open, you are setting a standard which allows for any such question with $50$ replaced by any other number.  It is too localized.  Think of the extreme case.  I would not want $200$ different questions on this site each regarding what is interesting about some different integer.  There is no mathematical content there.  Upvotes do not constitute a valid reason for reopening.  One of the more upvoted threads on MO is about jokes, which _is_ off topic despite being voted up.

Answer (score 1):

I am attempting to have the following reopened- it is not a duplicate as is evident. [Card game-ordering a deck](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/244596/card-game-ordering-a-deck)

Comment: However, it does bear more than a passing resemblance to Problem 9 of the ongoing competition at http://mit.edu/primes/materials/2013/entproUSA13.pdf

Comment: @Layla Patil: If you want it reopened you should react to others' comments.

Answer (score 1):

[REOPENED] I would like [Covariant derivative on hypersurface in $\mathbb{R}^n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/245041/covariant-derivative-on-hypersurface-in-mathbbrn) reopened. It was closed as duplicate but I don't think the answer in the question it's supposedly a duplicate of answers all of the interesting questions the OP has raised.

Comment: I've re-opened. Since the original close vote was unilateral by a mod, I think it is okay to re-open unilaterally too.

Answer (score 1):

[REOPENED] This [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/296480/arithmetic-count-divisibility) has 3 votes to close as being an exact duplicate of [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/296089/prove-using-pigeon-hole), though both are completely different questions. Kindly pause and check if the two questions are really duplicate of each other, before voting to close them as duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

[Re-opened] I voted to close [How to create a function using the following?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/326952/how-to-create-a-function-using-the-following#comment707211_326952) because it was very badly presented, and it got closed. OP has improved the question to the point where I think it can be answered, so I have voted to reopen.

Answer (score 1):

[REOPENED] https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/210161/probability-and-permutation-and-combination looks no worse than a lot of questions on the site, and leads to some interesting mathematics (as per the answer I posted before the question was closed). Please consider voting to reopen.

Comment: It should be noted that although there are claims that it is from an exam, it is from $5$ months ago, so the exam claim is no longer relevant.

Comment: @user1729 There is a *single* claim: "It certainly appears to be asked on a cell phone for a multiple-choice exam". But I see not a shred of evidence to support that claim. It appears to be extreme speculation.

Comment: There's really nothing wrong with this question. I voted to reopen.

Comment: You do not count the authors first comment as at least a *shred* of evidence?

Comment: Shred of evidence: *please i need this question answer urgently,the answer are given 7!,3120,4080,0............please help me out*.

Comment: Currently two votes to reopen ... and two votes to delete. Please, let's not argue about the strength of the evidence that it's an exam question --- as already noted, that's no longer relevant.

Comment: Now up to 4/5 to reopen, and 2/3 to delete. A race to the finish!

Answer (score 1):

[REOPENED] (Thanks, all.)

I would like to see [Sum of squared/cubed combinations](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/391489/sum-of-squared-cubed-combinations) reopened. It asks for a closed-form solution to $$\sum{\binom nk}^3.$$

I originally nominated it for closure as a duplicate of [Sum of cubes of binomial coefficients](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/134747/sum-of-cubes-of-binomial-coefficients), which asks only for an asymptotic formula, because one of the answers there mentioned that there is provably no closed-form expression for this sum, and cited a reference.  But the answer didn't give the proof, and the cited reference doesn't either (your princess is in another castle!) leaving one to wonder just what sorts of closed-form expressions have been ruled out.

I think our site would be improved by a more detailed discussion of this question, so I have nominated it for reopening.

Answer (score 1):

[REOPENED] I think that [What set theory axioms do I need to believe in uncountable ordinals?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/402493/what-set-theory-axioms-do-i-need-to-believe-in-uncountable-ordinals) should be reopened. Granted, I was the one who initiated the closure, but as I remarked later:

> After giving more thought, I'm not sure if that's a complete duplicate of the above links (and I'd withdraw my vote to close if that was possible). This question can be read as a broader question than just the axiom of choice. True, it was particularly interested in the axiom of choice, but there are other axioms in ZFC that may or may not be used in that proof. Hence my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

[REOPENED] [This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/404893/8348) was requested to be closed because it was part of a then-current [Brilliant challenge](https://brilliant.org/i/Q4fWBT/).  It is no longer live, and seems like a reasonable question to re-open.  But the community should decide on its appropriateness.

So here's your chance to undo what a moderator did! (or at least played a part in doing.)

Answer (score 1):

[Re-opened]

The question [What is $e$? How does $e$ relate to its limit as $n \to \infty$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/418931/28900) was closed **again** as "not a real question." I still contend that the question is perfectly clear, if naïve about the various contexts in which the symbol $\infty$ and specific infinities are used.

The OP is new, and has so far received a fairly poor reception (perhaps understandable, given some of his apparent attitudes). Still, this is not a reason to close his questions (downvote them, perhaps, on a case-by-case basis, but not close them).

I would like to see the question (re)reopened.

Comment: I agree.  The OP is being a jerk in the comments, but the question itself is legit, just confused.

Answer (score 1):

[REOPENED] I would like to see [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/107862/conjugate-subgroup-strictly-contained-in-the-initial-subgroup) re-opened, because I would like to answer it.

Currently it is closed as a duplicate. However, it isn't *actually* a duplicate. Rather, an answer to the linked question ([this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/75613/the-set-of-all-x-such-that-xhx-1-subseteq-h-is-a-subgroup-when-h-leq-g) question) provides an answer to the question I want re-opened.

This means that there is nowhere to give a reply to the closed question, which is a flaw.

(Oh, and I should say that this is relevant to the here-and-now because [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/423328/if-g-is-a-group-h-is-a-subgroup-of-g-and-g-in-g-is-it-possible-that) appeared today which is a genuine duplicate of the question I want to reopen.)

*The comments below clarify certain points.*

Comment: Can the down-voter please explain why they believe the post should not be re-opened?

Comment: If an answer to the linked question provides an answer to the closed question then I believe there is a way for a moderator to merge the questions. A flag should alert a moderator to consider doing so. And can't the new question also be closed as a duplicate of the linked question, and merged?

Comment: @GerryMyerson The answer to the still-open question answers the other two questions as a kind of aside. So merging the answers would not work.

Comment: One annoying feature of this approach is that you'll have to re-open the recently closed question in order to close it as a duplicate of the correct question.

Comment: @JackSchmidt I do not quite follow what you mean. There is a chain of "duplicate" arrows $3\rightarrow 2\rightarrow 1$ (so $a\rightarrow b$ means that $a$ has been closed as a duplicate of $b$). $3\rightarrow 2$ is definitely correct, but I am claiming that $2\rightarrow 1$ is incorrect. This is incorrect because an answer to $2$ or $3$ would be inappropriate for $1$. Reopening $2$, which is what I am proposing, would require no shuffling of arrows.

Comment: Oh cool, I thought the chain went the other way. Voting to reopen then :-)

Comment: (reopened now, woo)

Answer (score 1):

[REOPENED] I would like to see [my question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/427383/infinite-divisibility-of-random-variable-vs-distribution) reopened, now that it has reformulated. As one commenter has pointed out, there actually is a valid point to be made, regarding the link I posted.

Answer (score 1):

[Now Deleted]

OP has put some work into improving https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/436733/trigonometry-right-angled-triangles#comment936496_436733, so I nominate it for re-opening.

EDIT: now deleted. Can a deleted question even be re-opened?

Comment: I think posting questions as a scanned file or photograph should be discouraged. It would be difficult to give the question not in this way, but an attempted solution should be typed out. Apart from anything else, you are expecting anyone who answers this to put in more effort than the OP has done! (Thus, I am *not* voting to re-open, although I have no qualms about others doing so.)

Comment: I agree that what OP has done is not optimal. I think OP deserves some credit for engaging with criticism.

Comment: Question currently has 4 votes to reopen --- and 2 votes to delete.

Answer (score 1):

[Re-opened]

[How to calculate the exponent of a given number.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/442847/how-to-calculate-the-exponent-of-a-given-number/442860#442860)

This question has been put on hold because it's "not clear what you're asking", but I think it's entirely clear. It may not be expressed in mathematical jargon (it's obvious that the OP doesn't have the training required to do so), but you can still easily tell. The OP wants to know the inverse function of $x\to1.1^x$. This is possibly a programmer needing this for some project.

The only answer given is useless to the OP as it assumes they know what a logarithm is - they wouldn't be asking if they did - and merely states the obvious. All that's needed is a link to the Wikipedia article on logs and an explanation of how to use them.

Answer (score 1):

[REOPENED] I would like to see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/450939/direct-product-of-cyclic-group) homework question re-opened. It is not merely a demand for a solution, as the OP is interacting with the comments. Therefore, I see no reason why this should remain closed. (As a side point - the OP was interacting with the comments *before* it was closed. So I feel it should never have been closed).

Answer (score 1):

[REOPENED]

This question [cosets of $\mathbb Z[i] (2+i)$ in $\mathbb Z[i]$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/455157/cosets-of-mathbbzi2i-in-mathbbzi/455173#455173) was closed as a duplicate of an earlier question [Quotient rings of Gaussian integers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/23358/quotient-ring-of-gaussian-integers.)

However, the former question is asking for help on a particular proof approach, while the answers to the latter question are a medley of various possible approaches, none of which directly match with the OP of the former question's approach.

When someone posts a question with a sensible approach to solving a question, I would prefer that we help them develop that approach to fruition, rather than sending them off just to read a bunch of different approaches.  In this particular case, I already posted an answer with hints for the OP to complete their approach, and linked to the older question to indicate alternative  approaches, so in this particular case it doesn't really matter.  But as a matter of principle, I don't think this question counts as a duplicate, and so should not have been closed as such.

Answer (score 1):

[Prove $f=x^p-a$ either irreducible or has a root. (arbitrary characteristic) (without using the field norm)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/460931/prove-f-xp-a-either-irreducible-or-has-a-root-arbitrary-characteristic/) has been closed as a duplicate. But the answer at the earlier question uses field norms, and OP wants an answer not using field norms.

Answer (score 1):

[REOPENED]

[This post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/467514/221) (a commutative algebra question) was closed as unclear.  At this point the post seems to be entirely clear (there was clarification in the comments, which was then edited into the body of the post).

The question asks for help to prove something that is false.  This has been indicated in the comments, but it would be good if the post was reopened so that an actual counterexample with explanation could be posted as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

[REOPENED]

[This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/465180/programacion-lineal-pl) was originally posted in a language other than English and so was closed for being "unclear". It has been translated, and so should now be re-opened.

Answer (score 1):

[REOPENED]

I can’t for the life of me see what’s unclear about [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/484164/on-defining-sequences); André Nicolas, Andres Caicedo, and I have all addressed parts of it in the comments, and my comment would have been part of an answer had the question been open.

Answer (score 1):

[REOPENED]

[This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/489039/beginnings-of-greek-mathematics) has been put on hold for being off-topic, with the following explanation: "Homework questions must seek to understand the concepts being taught, not just demand a solution." The OP has now followed up with three comments, showing in my opinion sufficient effort for the question to be reopened.

Answer (score 1):

[REOPENED]

The OP of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/504623/43351) has responded to calls for extra information. They give the impression of being generally stuck -- understandable, due to being new to linear programming.

---

*Edit:* Shameless bump to rack up the last reopen vote.

Comment: Currently 4 votes to reopen.

Answer (score 1):

[REOPENED] Thank you.

The OP of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/507605/43351) has responded to calls for context, and is plainly stuck. They would like a hint.

Answer (score 1):

[REOPENED] Thanks.

OP of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/509893/43351) has given a nice bit of context that will allow an unambiguous interpretation of the question, and hence good answers.

Comment: The question asks for "the" derivative, but of what and with respect to what are not specified. The question is still not clear to me. (Evidently, the question is clear enough to OP, who claims in the comments to have solved it.)

Comment: It seems clear to me: OP has $\mathbf x(t)$, and wants $\mathbf x'(t)$.

Comment: OK, you got my vote.

Answer (score 1):

[REOPENED] Thanks.

OP of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/515818/43351) is in need of an answer (possibly a hint) that follows up on their work, which they added in response to my comment.

Answer (score 1):

[REOPENED]

[This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/525712/topology-general) question was recently marked as a duplicate of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/500700/neighborhood-and-upper-limit-topology-homework-help) earlier question. In my opinion, this was a poor decision. True, the solution to the question posed in the first link is given in the second link, but its accompanied by no proof, not even an explanation; and furthermore, the second link explicitly instructs the reader to *disregard* the question that the asker in the first link is actually interested in, so no proof or explanation will ever come.

I think the [duplicate] marking on the first link should be removed.

Answer (score 1):

[REOPENED]

[This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/533009/it-is-a-question-about-a-property-of-lebesgue-measure), closed as unclear, is now, after the OP’s response to a question, completely clear. I’ve incorporated that response into the body of the question.

Answer (score 1):

[REOPENED]

I would like to see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/536848/what-does-it-mean-to-be-an-instance-of-a-rewriting-rule) reopened. It is asking for the definition of something, and the OP has responded to a request for more clarification of where the definition cropped up. Therefore I see no reason for this question to remain closed.

(Although, in general I find it extremely bad form to close a question asking "what is the definition of X?". When such questions are closed it is often because those voting to close have never come across the term before, which is not one of the valid close reasons.)

Comment: In general I agree with not closing question about "What is X". But in this case, it's easily conceivable that multiple definitions could be given -- whence my close vote. With the reference added, it should be fine.

Comment: @Lord_Farin My point is that it is *easily conceivable* that multiple definitions could be given. But until someone comes along who actually knows something and says "multiple definitions could be given" then the question should not be closed.

Answer (score 1):

[REOPENED]

I would like to request that [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/538373/28900) be re-opened. (It is at present well on its way.) It was originally closed for missing context/details, as the OP had not shown any effort or shared any thoughts on the problem. However, the OP has now added an attempt at the problem (which is very nearly correct), so the question should be re-opened.

Answer (score 1):

[REOPENED] Thanks!

Please consider reopening [*Present a function with specific feature*](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/539741/462), about whether $f'(a)>0$ implies that $f$ is increasing.

People objected to the lack of context in the question, but my impression is that this is precisely the point of the question, that there is confusion about the concept itself, and some of the answers have indeed tried to address that.

I think the answers may be useful not just to the OP but others, and keeping the question open may be closer to the spirit of the site (This is indeed a generous reading of the situation, but I find it justified by the answers.)

(See also [here](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/a/1047/6085) for a similar discussion in meta at MO.)

Answer (score 1):

Will you please to reopen https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/511326/specific-advice-tips-to-streamline-studying-math by virtue of its upvotes and those on my Answer.

Will you please to appreciate the fact that most of the downvotes in its Meta thread (http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/11145/how-to-adapt-or-emend-specific-advice-tips-to-streamline-studying-math) occurred before my edit to my question, and observe Lord_Farin's gracious comment underneath his answer thereunder.

Comment: Relevant: Being successful at mathematics is about good communication as well as good ideas. I feel that this question is interesting, but presented poorly. It is just rather convoluted and too wordy. But I have voted to re-open, because I don't think that that is a valid reason for a question to be kept closed.

Comment: @user1729: Thank you for your support. I've pruned the OP somewhat. Please feel free to edit if seasonable!

Comment: I don't see how your edits have changed the fact that the question is extremely broad.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft It may be broad, but it is also of general interest. Broad questions are frowned upon, but often are looked less critically if they are of general interest. For example: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/71874/can-i-use-my-powers-for-good is incredibly broad, as are many of the top-voted [soft-questions](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/soft-question?sort=votes&pageSize=50).

Answer (score 1):

[REOPENED]

[natural representation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/540831/natural-representation) was put on hold as unclear. The author has clarified the question.

Answer (score 1):

[REOPENED] Thanks.

[This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/545564/43351) was closed as "unclear what you're asking". At the time of closing, it had gone through multiple edit rounds, and had 4 answers.

In other words, it was perfectly clear to some what was being asked. It shouldn't have been closed in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

[NEVER MIND]

There's a revised Question [about "proportion" of prime numbers to non-prime numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/539192/3111) that the OP wishes to have reopened.

I'm somewhat lukewarm about this, but after reviewing our stock of Q's on the Prime Number Theorem, it seems some technical but valid to ask what the PNT tells us about the ratio of primes to non-primes (below a threshold natural number $n$).

If I felt the (new) user were more mathematically adept, I guess I'd be more enthusiastic about reopening.  However I suspect I'm projecting a meaning onto the request that is more sophisticated than what the OP is thinking.

Comment: I disagree. The question shouldn't have been edited in the first place (it invalidates existing answers), and I have reverted. Perhaps it should be a new question.

Comment: It seems the OP is happy with a Commenter's link to another Question, similar to the revised one that has been reverted.

Answer (score 1):

[REOPENED]

The author of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/547347/5531) has added their thoughts on the problem as requested.  It was originally closed with the "missing context" reason.

Answer (score 1):

[REOPENED]

[This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/550773/proof-by-direct-method) was put on hold as unclear, since the term *throdd* and the abbreviation PBAC were not explained. I’ve added the definition of *throdd* from an earlier question by the same person and expanded the abbreviation, which I’ve encountered before. (It’s *particular but arbitrarily chosen*.)

Answer (score 1):

[REOPENED]

The OP of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/570030/when-is-the-ring-of-continuous-functions-noetherian) question has [reposted](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/570200/noetherianty-of-ring-of-continuous-functions) the question in more precise terms. I thought it was safe to edit the original to reflect his/her expressed question, and I think it's worth reopening with the added details (note that the answer already existing only mentions a compact Hausdorff $X$, whereas the OP didn't seem to want the scope to be thus limited).

Answer (score 1):

[REOPENED]

The author of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/570452/11619) solved the problem after I suggested an approach. Please reconsider now.

Answer (score 1):

[REOPENED] Thanks, once again.

> [Variable weight according to distance.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/580442/43351)

OP has greatly clarified their question, and a comment inquiry gave enough information to bring it to answerable form. Please reopen.

Answer (score 1):

[REOPENED]

It seems that I was too quick to suggest closing this question as an exact duplicate: [Find the limit of $(\sqrt2-\root3\of2 )(\sqrt2 -\root4\of2 )...(\sqrt 2-\root{n}\of2 )$ without using the squeezing principle](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/551301/find-the-limit-of-sqrt2-root3-of2-sqrt2-root4-of2-sqrt-2-rootn)

As Thomas Andrews says [in his comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/551301/find-the-limit-of-sqrt2-root3-of2-sqrt2-root4-of2-sqrt-2-rootn#comment1237300_551301) this question asks explicitly about proofs *not using squeezing theorem*.

The other questions about the same limit do not have such proof. ([Finding the limit of roots products $(\sqrt{2}-\sqrt[3]{2})(\sqrt{2}-\sqrt[4]{2})(\sqrt{2}-\sqrt[5]{2})\cdot \cdot \cdot (\sqrt{2}-\sqrt[n]{2})$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/452173/finding-the-limit-of-roots-products-sqrt2-sqrt32-sqrt2-sqrt42), [What is $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}(\sqrt2-\sqrt[3]2)\cdots(\sqrt2-\sqrt[n]2)$? How to approach?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/549111/what-is-lim-limits-n-to-infty-sqrt2-sqrt32-cdots-sqrt2-sqrtn2-ho))

Answer (score 1):

[REOPENED]

The author of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/588460/rearranging-numbered-cards-to-reverse-their-order?noredirect=1#comment1244446_588460) has offered an example which I think now makes the question clear.

Answer (score 1):

[REOPENEND]

[Limit of $\sqrt{x^2-6x+7}-x$ as x approaches negative infinity](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/603628/limit-of-sqrtx2-6x7-x-as-x-approaches-negative-infinity)
This question was closed as *missing context or other details*.

User comments, in particular [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/603628/limit-of-sqrtx2-6x7-x-as-x-approaches-negative-infinity#comment1271583_603628) show that they made some effort. (I hope the OP will post his solution either as an answer or edit it into the question after it is reopened.)

I think the question should be reopened.

Answer (score 1):

[REOPENED]

[This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/610245/group-acting-on-a-set/610303) was closed as missing context or other details.

The OPs replies to my hint demonstrate that they are thinking about what is going on. They are not just after some quick and easy solution for a homework question which they can hand in.

Therefore, I think the question should be reopened.

Answer (score 1):

[This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/623536/) about radian measures was recently marked as a duplicate of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3198/proof-that-pi-is-constant-the-same-for-all-circles-without-using-limits) about $\pi$ being the same for all circles. The former question asks 2 concrete questions in its body, and I feel that at most one of them is covered by the latter question. I think it would be better if the question about $\pi$ were mentioned in a comment, rather than designated a duplicate.

Note: I don't have 3000 rep, so when counting reopen votes, don't count mine.

Answer (score 1):

[REOPENED]

I think the following question should be re-opened.

[Content of the book "Group Theory Seminar Lectures:1960-1961"](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/635266/content-of-the-book-group-theory-seminar-lectures1960-1961)

The question is asking about the contents of a specific book. I cannot find anything on the internet about what is in this book, and it is not in my uni's library. I fail to see how this question can possible be "too broad". Presumably it contains some papers, so the titles of these papers would be a sufficient answer. A more vague answer, for example saying "finite $p$-groups" would also be clearly acceptable.

If you do not think that this question should be re-opened, then I would be interested to know how you would suggest the OP found out this information, without having to buy this book?

Comment: The question as posed *is* too broad, and lacks context. You have now gotten some useful comments on it, but for the future, you could have 1. explained why you are interested in it, 2. explained that you have been unable to find any information about what it contains, 3. explained that you were looking for very general information rather than all the theorems and proofs contained in the book.

Comment: @dfeuer I was the one who provided the useful comments, not the OP. .. (Also, from the context, I believe that (3) was clear.)

Answer (score 1):

Please reopen https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/644699/whats-mathbbz-2-times-z-4-mathbbz-3-times-z-8-isomorphic-to-frale

I removed the darkred color but can add it back. Please notify me which is better. My questions are marked with numbers (1.) to (3.). Hence any color problems should now be settled.

Comment: The question has since been deleted automatically.

Answer (score 1):

[REOPENED]

Please Reopen [Aleph and omega - were these deliberately chosen to represent infinities because of the connection between God (the alpha and the omega) and infinity?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/644200/462)

It is a reasonable reference request on whether Cantor's (well documented) views on religion influenced his choice of notation. I think there are common misconceptions here, and this question can be a good place to at least start addressing them.

Comment: While possibly interesting, I fail to see how it is a question about *mathematics*.

Answer (score 1):

[REOPENED]

[This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/657927/linear-algebra-complex-numbers) was unilaterally put on hold by a moderator, as missing context and details. The question has since been edited to include the thoughts and efforts of the asker, and so should be reopened.

Answer (score 1):

[REOPENED]

I recently asked [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/724228/expectation-of-a-poisson-process) and was told it was a duplicate. However, the said "original" question did not satisfactorily answer my question. I was looking to solve the problem a specific way, the other answer took a different approach. Not only that, but my question turned out to be algebraic and calculus based; I did not have a question about the specific probability laws, but whether or not I was using them correctly because I thought I had a recurrence relation. I would like the question reopened so that I may give proper credit to the commenter who answered my question; which, I repeat, was not answered by the "original."

Answer (score 1):

Please reopen https://math.stackexchange.com/q/696131/85079. I revised the question. Language and content are clear now. Closers didn't comment on what they were vexed about so I tried to guess.

Answer (score 1):

[REOPENED]

Please reopen [If every convergent subsequence converges to $a$, then so does the original bounded sequence (Abbott p 58 q2.5.4 and q2.5.3b)](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/776899/85079)

I revised the question. Language and content are clear now. I tried to guess what closers didn't understand because they didn't comment. Please write me if something needs to be bettered.

Comment: The reason for closure was explicitly given. No need to "guess" what it was. You [already requested](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/13540/462) the original post to be undeleted and open.

Answer (score 1):

[Re-opened]

Please consider whether [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/780997/11619) should be reopened.

I am not 100% sold on the question meeting our quality standards myself. But I disagree with the close reason, as IMHO the original version was already clear about what was being asked. The question asks about a specific detail of a planar motion. I took the liberty of adding a few animations hopefully making it clear to all what that motion looks like. The OP's notation is non-standard, but I explained that in a comment (just to make sure - IMO there is only one sensible interpretation). I am bit reluctant to edit the notation, as that might hurt OP's chances of understanding an eventual answer.

My interpretation is that the original close voter was taken aback by the odd notation, terse problem description, and the air of a HW problem. The others observed the same weaknesses, and then followed suit. If I misinterpreted the close-voters motives, then I apologize for my own trigger-happiness.  All those weaknesses are undeniable, but I voted to reopen this, because IMO there is a well-defined answerable question in here. Checking out the OP's profile makes it probable that the OP is in self-study mode, so I am not worried about any cheating taking place here.

I do not intend to answer the question myself. Leaving that to the interested calculus-experts. After looking at the animations I would be very surprised, if my guess about the correct answer would not pop out :-)

Comment: Even if the question is clear, it's completely lacking context and any sense of what the person asking it has tried. Unless that person edits the question, it may end up closed again (possibly with a different reason) if it is reopened.

Comment: I think it looks like an interesting question, but I had some difficulty understand it, because I did not recognize the notation.  I saw from the comments that others were confused by the notation also.  So I changed the notation and the voted to reopen.

Comment: Currently 4 votes to reopen....

Comment: I am the OP in this particular case. (Don't know the phrase for which OP stands, but context that I have seen suggests that it stands for “the submittor of a question.”) Pp By popular demand, I have reworked my question. As to the question, What have you done?, my answer is, All that my puny education, both formal and self-attained, would enable me to do. I have tried to teach myself calculus with a bit of success, but perhaps not enough that I can go further on this self-posed problem. Ergo, my question.

Comment: OP = Original Poster (sometimes, Original Post). Indications of what you have done belong at the OP, not here.

Answer (score 1):

Will you please to reopen [Intuition - Countable iff Surjection iff Injection [Velleman P310 Thm 7.1.5]](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/752959/intuition-countable-iff-surjection-iff-injection-velleman-p310-thm-7-1-5)?

I asked this separately from [my other question strictly about the proof that is now deleted](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/751497/countable-iff-surjection-iff-injection-velleman-p310-thm-7-1-5). It shouln't be esteemed a duplicate, because in addition to intuition, I'm also interested in a picture. For want of organisation and focus, I didn't want to ask about all three aspects in one question.

Answer (score 1):

[Re-opened]

The question [Portia casket logic problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/790910/39378) was incorrectly (I believe) marked as a duplicate.  I guess no one noticed my comment to this effect, or my answer, which contradicts the accepted answer to the other question and should make the difference between the questions clear.

Answer (score 1):

[REOPENED; RECLOSED]

Please consider reopening [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/814884/is-there-a-formula-for-mertens-function-mx-sum-n-leq-x-mu-n).  Although the question itself may be naive, it does seem clear enough.

Comment: Needs 2 reopen votes.

Comment: @BillDubuque - It seems that the question got reopened and then closed again, because the OP doesn't provide attempts to solve the "problem".  Do you have any idea why this question is controversial, but [this one](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/791378/can-sqrtp-sqrtp-sqrtp-be-an-integer-if-p-is-a-non-square-posit), which doesn't per se provide "work shown" or attempts to solve, is wildly popular?  I visit this site only very sporadically, and I am rather unclear on the current standards being applied to questions.

Comment: No, I strongky disagree with such closures. This is one of many bad side-effects of the extremely poor design of the SE platform.

Comment: @Bill Dubuque: I think the solution here is to avoid re-opening these questions before the OP edits them. Although I have not voted to close, I pointed out before the question was re-opened that it would still be a candidate for closure.

Comment: @John M: I speculate that the difference is some combination of: (1) the level of the question (2) the fact that one is on standard facts, while the other is open, and (3) different people see different questions. It would be ideal for Sawarnik's question ( http://math.stackexchange.com/q/791378/630 ) to include something else, perhaps an explanation of where the problem was encountered.

Comment: @CarlMummert I disagree. Rather, I think the solution it to avoid closing them in the first place. Instead, users that are biased against any particular class of questions should lobby SE to give them better ways to filter questions. Forcing such bias globally onto the entire community is a recipe for failure.

Comment: @Bill Dubuque: This issue has been discussed at length on meta, as you are well aware. For example, see http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9201/proposal-discourage-questions-that-are-nothing-besides-a-problem-statement/9342#9342 , which has 65 upvotes (+87/-19) at this moment. Moreover, there would not be a "lacking context" reason in the closure menu if community support for it was not patently clear. Therefore, nobody is "forcing such bias" onto the community. The community simply **has** a bias against such questions, for reasons of which I am certain you are already aware.

Comment: @Carl As I said, the SE platform is extremely poorly designed. It makes no sense to expect "majority" opinions to be wise on topics (like teaching) where the majority (students) have little to no experience. And if you think that you should have the right to choose for others what questions they are allowed to value/answer then we have such widely disparate views on how such a general level math forum should function that there is little point in continuing.

Comment: @Carl In any case, as I wrote when I created this thread, this is not supposed to be a place for such discussion.

Comment: @Bill Dubuque: this thread was created by John M, not by you. I think that the thread for each question for which re-opening is requested is a reasonable place to discuss the merits of that question. What I would not find reasonable would be to claim that it is somehow surprising that the question here was closed - *the question is an obvious candidate for closure in its present form*. That ship has sailed. But there is an ongoing need to help users understand the community consensus on these matters (which, I want to emphasize, was shaped by *teachers* concerned with low quality questions!).

Comment: @Carl - Thanks very much!  I think I get the gist of the issues involved.

Comment: @Bill - Thank very much!  I think I now get the gist of the issues involved.

Comment: @Carl The "thread" refers to this entire thread, i.e. the reopen request thread (which was proposed and designed by me, even though Asaf morphed his question into it before I had a chance to discuss and post it - see the comments to the question). As the question says, this thread is not intended for extensive discussion.

Answer (score 1):

[REOPENED]

I don't think that [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/818447/positive-harmonic-function-must-be-constant) is actually a duplicate. The newer question begins with a function harmonic on the unit disk, while the linked question has a function  harmonic on the whole space.

Answer (score 1):

[REOPENED]

I am requesting that [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/838287/deradicalization-of-denominators) be reopened. It was originally a mess (question and answer all in one), but has since been cleaned up.

Comment: The question now has $4$ votes to close, all based on "missing context or details." I'd guess from people who don't see the fact that it's self-answered.

Comment: @user61527: does that make a difference when the question is drafted in a way that immediately suggests closure? I am not convinced that we want to encourage self-answered questions; I have several concerns about them. But certainly we can expect them to be exceptional both in the drafting of the question and the drafting of the answer.

Comment: @CarlMummert I agree that questions like this should generally contain the answer in the question statement (or at a minimum clearly mark that they are self-answered), but I don't think that this is a reason for closure.

Answer (score 1):

[REOPENED]

I'd like to request that [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/842801/topology-opens-vs-neighborhoods?noredirect=1#comment1740911_842801) be reopened. The OP has clarified what the question is and in fact answered it himself yesterday. Therefore the reasons of lack of clarity or lack of effort are not valid for leaving it closed.

Answer (score 1):

[REOPENED]

[This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/853178/5531) was closed as a duplicate of a previous question.  However, the previous question has a rather incomplete answer while the new one (the duplicate) received a very detailed answer.  The new question should be reopened since it's more "canonical".

Answer (score 1):

[REOPENED]

[This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/878567/power-series-and-their-inverses-radius-of-convergence-of-each) was closed for lacking context. It has now been improved, and should be reopened.

Answer (score 1):

[REOPENED]

Please consider reopening [Find parameters of short geometric series](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/883023/3111).  In its original form the Question was a slightly puzzling query-by-example, but it has now been clarified.  I think it has the makings of good content.

Although the problem is upon analysis like the old chestnut of [finding compound interest rate parameters](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/207864/3111), the User's application is different.  The User hopes to solve such problems "by algebra" and may well learn that, apart from mere trial-and-error, such polynomial root finding needs a touch more math.

Answer (score 1):

Please vote for undelete the following question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/601765/dimension-and-multiplicity-of-modules-over-rings-not-generated-in-degree-one which I think can be of interest for the future users of M.SE.

Comment: Did you contact the author of the question (since they chose to delete it several months ago)?

Comment: @Did Actually I can't see who is the author of the question. (Only users rated >10k can see a deleted question/answer.)

Comment: But you do see the question, right (since you want it to be reopened)?

Comment: @Did Of course not, but I've commented on this question some time ago and I remember that the question was interesting enough.

Comment: There is no comment whatsoever on this question (which was deleted on April, 5). Not sure I am following what is going on here...

Comment: @Did The most probably I've deleted my comment after a while if there wasn't any feedback from the OP.

Comment: @Did: Note that there is a deleted answer, by a deleted user, whose user number corresponds to this user's username. I am guessing this is someone who went away and came back for one reason or another. Which is how they know about this question.

Answer (score 1):

[UNDELETED, REOPENED]

I'd like to ask for [How is greater than defined for real numbers?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/964329/how-is-greater-than-defined-for-real-numbers/) to be undeleted.

It is true that the phrasing is very poor, and the question itself has a very negative score. However I think that the answers, and the many comments below them, have a lot of information that is worth preserving.

Comment: I think the question would need to be edited first, and the comments with refer to the orginal form deleted. They detract from the maths. So in principle I agree, but I won't vote to reopen yet.

Comment: I didn't ask for it to be reopened. :-) But if someone sees a reasonable way to edit, and flags the comments which need to be deleted, that would be a good idea.

Comment: I have deleted the silly stuff in the question, and flagged the relevant comments. Perhaps someone could add some context? But, well, I do not know if it is really necessary for definition questions...

Comment: Asaf, @user1729 I have added a few sentences which could be considered as *adding context*. (Per the recommendation to [improve questions](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/16451/is-there-an-mse-like-site-that-is-more-pleasant-to-work-in-or-are-there-other-s/16485#16485), which I want them to stay on the site.)  Feel free to rollback, if you disagree with the changes. (Or, perhaps better option, feel free to improve questions further.)

Comment: @Martin I think your edit is above and beyond what I'd consider necessary. I've cast the third-and-final reopen vote. I would still like those comments to be removed though.

Comment: @user1729: You continuously confuse reopening and undeleting. But it's fine, I guess. :-P

Comment: @Asaf Words are not my thing. Although...I did spend much of my PhD studying words (in group theory)...

Comment: (Just to be clear: I *meant* undelete, *not* reopen. What I say is not always what I mean. Which make writing papers...interesting...)

Answer (score 1):

[REOPENED]

[This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/990676/some-combinatorial-proofs#990676) should never have been put on hold in the first place, as it was obvious that the OP was asking for verification of the arguments. This request has now been explicitly added, and the question should be reopened.

Comment: I do not understand the downvotes here. How is this contentious?!?

Answer (score 1):

[REOPENED]

The question [isotopy of homeomorphisms of a torus](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/990811/isotopy-of-homeomorphisms-of-a-torus) was edited to make it a viable mathematical question, which now can be read as "How to show that a homeomorphism of a torus which is homotopic to the identity is isotopic to the identity?". This is now a good question, which fits into the general framework of topological rigidity problems and should be reopened.

Answer (score 1):

[REOPENED]

The question [Monty Hall Problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1010434/monty-hall-problem) was closed as duplicate.

It does however not ask for the usual Monty Hall Problem but a variant thereof. 
There is some very small room of interpretation what is meant exactly but I feel it is clear enough and is answerable.

The answer is not obvious in my opinion (there are other variants that are simpler) and while it is discussed on the linked to question it is somewhat implict and in an answer way down by votes; I feel at least this should have been indicated. But actually I feel the question should be answered on its own.

Answer (score 1):

[UNDELETED][REDELETED][REUNDELETED]

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/432742/calculate-start-middle-and-end-of-any-number was closed as "unclear what you are asking" *after* it had an answer accepted by the poster (so it was clear to at least one person what OP was asking). Then a year-and-a-half later it was deleted, despite having an upvoted, accepted answer. I have voted to undelete.

EDIT: Question (and answer) redeleted (after I edited to clarify question). I have (re)voted to re-undelete.

Answer (score 1):

[REOPENED]

I don't think [Unbounded family of functions from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{N}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/243413/unbounded-family-of-functions-from-mathbbn-to-mathbbn) should be closed as a duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/243044/the-family-of-all-unbounded-functions-on-natural-numbers-is-uncountable

The main difference (between the current versions) is that one asks to show that *any unbounded family is uncountable*. (In the other words, this is asking for the proof that the $\mathfrak b\ge\aleph_1$, where $\mathfrak b$ denotes the [bounding number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinal_characteristic_of_the_continuum).) The other one asks to show that *the family of all unbounded functions is uncountable*. These are clearly two different questions.

In addition to that, the first question asks about $\leq^*$-unbounded families. The other does not specify this, but I would expect that it asks about the usual notion of unbounded function.

It is quite probable that the OP wanted to post the same question, but the two questions are definitely not the same (the way they are worded).

Review on the question I have mentioned above is already finished. With the result [leave closed](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/326392).

Answer (score 0):

[This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/418907/78535) was closed as a duplicate of [this one.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/404157/78535) However, the proposed duplicate question seeks only answers *not* using modular arithmetic, whereas the recent question uses modular arithmetic. The OP of the  former question emphasized this restriction when I posted my answer in the old question (since the current one was closed while I composed my answer).

Answer (score 0):

[REOPENED]

[This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/434365/28900) has been closed as a duplicate of [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/433580/28900). While two of the five parts are the same and the other three are similar, it is not, in fact, a duplicate (except, perhaps, in the vaguest sense that they are asking the same *kinds* of questions). I request that it be reopened.

Comment: Cameron, had this question been even remotely well-written, and show any hint of effort I'd be glad to vote for reopening. Two of the five statements are exact copies, two more differ by what I can't tell whether or not is an actual difference or **very sloppy typing**; and the fifth one is most definitely a duplicate of some other question on the site.

Comment: @Asaf: Fair enough. I'm not opposed to the question being closed in principle. I'd merely like the close reason to be an accurate representation of the situation.

Comment: Cameron, since I lost my closure privileges on that question and it's *really* not a good question, what would you suggest that should happen when the next person casts a reopen vote? Should the parts which are exact duplicate from the other thread be removed, then the question should be closed as a duplicate of some other question? Should the question be closed as unclear/ambiguous/effortless post? I'm all ears.

Comment: It isn't a good question, true. That's certainly reason not to upvote it, and arguably reason to downvote it. The closure rules did just get revamped, so maybe there's even reason to close it, but the reason given isn't quite right. I'm not quite sure what to do, though. I have put this forth as a question on meta [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/10140/28900), if you'd like to give your input.

Answer (score 0):

[REOPENED] [This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/451381/what-is-the-maximum-of-the-self-root-fx-x1-x) should be re-opened because, the words of the OP,

"I was sharing my knowledge not homework. I saw that you could answer your own questions Q&A style."

[Which is allowed!](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/) Need I say more? (Other than, perhaps, can people please be more careful when they close a question?)

Comment: I do not agree. Here is my comment at that question: *"This site is meant as a Q&A-site for questions, with which you stuck and for which you need other peoples help. It is not meant as a site where we create a repository of problems &  answers out of some books or from your own compilations. (Why not creating such a site if it does not yet exist?)"*    http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/451381/what-is-the-maximum-of-the-self-root-fx-x1-x#comment973196_451381  . There is also one more comment of mine against a subsequent argument.

Comment: @GottfriedHelms You are disagreeing with a specific functionality of the site. If you disagree with it you should start a Meta question discussing it, rather than close a question which uses it.

Comment: I'm disagreeing with misusing a functionality of a site against its intention. As everybody knows about software implementation, often some functionality of a software cannot be avoided (or was not seen in the begnning) which allows to counter the intention of the software. (For instance, the functionality also allows spam, but this is not intended). As I told in the comment at the question, I'll do not continue that discussion on this level of disagreement with you (it's a fundamental disagreement over the intention of our site)

Comment: @GottfriedHelms I don't understand your point. The OP of this question was using this functionality in the way it was designed to be used! (And as I said in the question, I am not claiming to hold an opinion about the basic intention of this site (hence I cannot be disagreeing with you about it). Rather, I am pointing out an existing functionality. What I have an opinion about is that someone should not be criticised for using this functionality.)

Comment: There is no agreement that this sort of thing is ok at MSE. Just because something is allowed on stackoverflow does not mean it is allowed on all the sites in the stackexchange network (that said, there is also not an agreement that it is not ok).

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft It has been discussed before. The most recent Meta question I could find is from a year ago, [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4680/is-answering-own-question-okay/4690#4690). It seems that the opinion was "This is okay, just don't make the site into your personal blog/soapbox", but perhaps I have misinterpreted this (mostly my interpretation comes from Henning Makholm's post).

Comment: But one thing mentioned in the answer by Henning is that an obvious requirement should be that the asker would feel this is something someone else might want to look up on the site. But for this question, there is already a question asking about differentiating $x^x$ which is completely analogous, so no need for one with $x^{1/x}$.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Then the question should be closed as a duplicate.

Comment: (@TobiasKildetoft As an aside: Should we perhaps be discussing this feature on meta properly? I can see both sides of the argument and it *is* contentious, so perhaps it should have an annual airing?)

Comment: That might be a good idea, though I doubt any sort of consensus will be found.

Answer (score 0):

The person who asked [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/508162/some-separation-axiom-dont-imply-another-one) has now added the missing photograph, and it’s now clear what is wanted: an example of a regular, non-normal space other than the Sorgenfrey plane. I expect that the OP would like a simpler example. (Note: it’s clear from the photo that the notes use the backwards convention in which $T_3$ and $T_4$ do **not** include $T_1$.)

Comment: You seem to be putting much of yourself into this: according to their own comments, the OP does not ask for an example of a space with such-and-such properties, they want to "know whether (their) examples are correct or incorrect". (Unrelated: are you actually able to read the photograph?)

Comment: @Did: That comment hadn’t yet been made when I posted this request. I actually can read the photo with a bit of work just as Firefox displays it on the question page, but I don’t bother: it’s easy to read when I open the image in a new tab and view it at actual size instead of reduced to fit the screen.

Comment: The chronology is irrelevant to my point. What do you think of "it’s now clear what is wanted" in your post here?

Comment: @Did: Isn’t it obvious? What he said at the time was reasonably clear; it also turns out not to have been what he wanted to say. *shrug* It happens. It’s also beside the main point, which is that he added the missing photo.

Comment: Sorry but as far as we know the OP always said exactly what they wanted to say. I have no idea why you pretend otherwise (furthermore, declaring that it is "obvious" that they did). But hey, this universe is full of mysteries, aint'it?

Comment: @Did: If you really believe your first sentence, you must live in an ivory tower and have very little contact with real people.

Comment: Thanks for the compliment. Of course, the first sentence refers to this OP and to this question, not to every question and every user on the site (to even imagine that I would argue that in every question etc. ..., wow!). And "always" refers to the fact that at no stage of the question, the OP said what you based your request for reopening upon.

Answer (score 0):

[REOPENED]

Please reopen [Are these sets with orbits subgroups of $S_A$ = set of all permutations of A? - Fraleigh p. 86 8.41-8.43](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/634977/are-these-sets-with-orbits-subgroups-of-s-a-set-of-all-permutations-of-a).

My questions are marked with numbers (1.) to (3.) and I already updated the question. Therefore I don't see what's 'unclear what you're asking'?

The people who closed did not comment on what's 'unclear'.

Answer (score 0):

The 2012 question [Prime counting inequality](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/236823/) was put "on hold" two days ago, with the reason "unclear what you are asking".

I think the question is clear: what is the largest $c$ such that $\pi(x)>cx/\ln x$ for all  integers $x$ [in the range where function $\pi$ makes sense]? It admits an  answer: $c=\ln 2/2$.  Not a very exciting answer, but  not entirely trivial either. 
I see no reason at all for this question to be closed.

Comment: Ah, but you are misquoting the question: it was asked for all integers $n$, not $x$. This led to a commenter asking whether $n$ was supposed to be $x$, a question which the author did not answer. So, technically, the question is unclear. But on the whole I don't see where closing it does any good.

Answer (score 0):

Please reopen https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/713610/having-elements-as-ideals . The question is in my opinion clear (I have edited it to make it maximally clear). The main problem of clarity seems to be other people assuming I am unclearly expressing an idea other than the idea I am expressing explicitly, because its such an odd idea/question. That is, they assume I am being unclear or figurative because they refuse to take my words at face value.

Comment: Without rendering a judgement on the question itself, "The main problem of clarity seems to be other people assuming I am unclearly expressing an idea other than the idea I am expressing" seems to be the very definition of "unclear."

Comment: @T.Bongers Point well taken. I clarify in the next sentence what I mean though. People are assuming I am being figurative or mistaken, instead of just reading the words I am writing as literal.

Answer (score 0):

[REOPENED]

The question [Unions and the axiom of choice.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/732051/unions-and-the-axiom-of-choice) was edited and some context was given. I'd like to see it reopened so I can post an answer.

Answer (score 0):

[REOPENED] for the 2nd time

[This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/751539/proof-that-a-product-of-two-quasi-compact-spaces-is-quasi-compact-without-axiom) was put on hold because it shows no effort.
I edited the question to show my effort.
I hope it will be reopened.

Comment: I am voting to reopen; the current closure reason no longer applies to the question: There is now sufficient context and details. Although I would strongly prefer that in the future the question be self-contained (e.g. the proof to be discussed / analyzed is provided in the question, rather than in an answer added later), I don't think this is reason for closure.

Comment: I agree with @T.Bongers and have voted to reopen (and will post an answer if reopened).

Answer (score 0):

Please reopen https://math.stackexchange.com/q/709609/85079 
https://math.stackexchange.com/q/676630/85079

I revised the question. Language and content are clear now. Closers didn't comment on what they were vexed about, but please tell me if anything needs to be bettered.

Answer (score 0):

[REOPENED]

Please reopen [A sequence converges $\iff$ it's Cauchy. Proof of ($\Leftarrow$) (Abbott p 59 t2.6.4)](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/779975/85079)

I revised the question. I tried to revise the issues in the comments. Please write me if something needs to be bettered.

Answer (score 0):

Please reopen 
https://math.stackexchange.com/q/771467/53934

My questions are marked and I already updated the question. Therefore I don't see what's 'unclear what you're asking'?

Comment: Combining the quoted text, the image in the question, and that there are at least two external links that have to be read to complete the question, it's a rather difficult read.

Comment: The question has since been auto-deleted.

Answer (score 0):

[Re-opened]

I think that [How large can the internet be?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/788294/how-large-can-the-internet-be#comment1633319_788294), a simple combinatorics question, should be re-opened. It was closed because with the way the OP phrased it, it required knowledge on conventions for URLs, but now the OP has provided a mathematically clear definition of "URL" (see the comments) and the question can be answered.

Answer (score 0):

[REOPENED; RECLOSED]

I am requesting that [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/828557/is-there-any-formal-definition-or-reasonably-good-heuristic-for-mathematical-in) be re-opened.

I think it is an interesting question. It remind me of model theory and of category theory - it is almost a meta-mathematical question. I have no idea if it can be answered *but that is no reason for it to be closed*. That is: it is a question that *so far* noone knows how to answer it, but that does not mean that it does not admit an answer.

Comment: Would the downvoter care to comment? I want to hear your opinion :-)

Comment: The question now has $4$ reopen votes.

Comment: And now at $4$ votes to close.

Answer (score 0):

[REOPENED; RECLOSED]

[This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/865561/how-would-you-change-math-notation) should be reopened.  It originally contained an opinion that has since been deleted from it, and apparently in consequence of that now-deleted opinion it was closed as an opinion-based question.  Per Manne's comment under the question is a good answer, but it cannot be posted as an answer.

Comment: If 'How would you change math notation' is not 'primarily opinion-based', I don't know what is.

Comment: I agree with reopening this question, but I think it ought to be made CW (and probably tagged [tag:big-list]).

Comment: Two people are reported to have voted to re-open this question after it was closed for the second time.  I am told that I cannot vote to reopen it again.  Are only those who didn't vote to reopen it the first time allowed to vote now?

Comment: @Michael: This is how I remember the behavior for quite a long time now. You get one close vote, you get one reopen vote; you get infinite delete and undelete votes (although using all of them may pose a challenge to modern physics, since there is a 30 delete votes daily limit).

Answer (score 0):

[REOPENED]

I would like to request to open this thread https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/886640/linear-transformation-representing-the-derivative-of-map.

The given reason was - "This question is missing context or other details: Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level." – 900 sit-ups a day, Ivo Terek, rogerl, le gâteau au fromage, Adam Hughes

However, I had already answered my own question. I wanted people to comment on my answer. I had already put down my thoughts below and they put it on hold for the question lacking the same!  They should not have done what they did!

Answer (score 0):

[This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/210161/probability-and-permutation-and-combination) was closed and there are two votes to delete. If it is deleted, then my answer gets deleted with it. I think my answer contributes useful mathematical content to m.se, and I ask you not to vote to delete.

If the question does get deleted, consider this a request for undeletion.

EDIT: Never mind. Question got deleted, so I [reposted](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/920057/how-many-permutations-avoid-previous-adjacencies/920058#920058) it myself, with my answer.

Comment: Needs 2 more undelete votes. How very sad that a small group of users are repeatedly destroying valuable site content in this manner. Yet another major flaw in the SE model.

Comment: It's a PSQ from what looks like a throwaway account. The fact that the answer doesn't match any of the options specified by the OP means that the OP misstated their intended question, or that it was misunderstood. In either case, we'll never know, apart from the miniscule chance that the OP returns to clarify. In that case, I would welcome an undeletion. Otherwise, deleting it seems like reasonable cleanup to me (it is voted -5 after all)

Comment: @BillDubuque Luckily there is [a model](https://answers.yahoo.com/) without this flaw.

Comment: @Thursday Yahoo! Glad to see that you found a more appropriate forum for your campaign.

Comment: I was one of the deleters. This was a tough call. Gerry's answer is most certainly worth keeping, but the question was abysmal. Reposting was a very good idea! Hopefully other people who feel that their deleted answers should stay on the site follow suit

Comment: How does the reposted question statement differ from the reposted one? Could someone shed some light on this for this measly 4-figure rep user?

Comment: @Daniel, at the time it was deleted, it read, "7 friends went to see a movie, at the time of interval they went away, in how many ways when they come back can seat that no 2 adjacent people will not seat together?"

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Could you explain why you think reposting a more or less verbatim copy of a question that you found was worthy of a delete vote is a very good idea?

Comment: I'm legitimately trying to understand why you would have gone to all this trouble, and not bothered to edit the actual question into something more comprehensible?  The authors original question no longer matters, it's now your question and a self-answer.  I can't see what is gained by not just making it, at least, a slightly better question.

Comment: @Scott, I thought I did make it a better question. Feel free to edit and make it even better.

Comment: @DanielR: A good question - in the sense that it isn't crystal clear. The original version had many tell-tale signs of a very bad question. One of the commenters even suggested that it was sent from an exam with a smartphone (broken/telegraph English tips that way, but is inconclusive as it came from a non-native speaker). Deleting such a question is then more about sending a signal. Reposting takes away the urgency/potential cheating aspect. Also Gerry can be relied upon to produce readable English. But, if your point was to somehow question my motives, then you may have a point...

Comment: (cont'd) It **IS** a lot easier to approve of a question when it carries a *Gerry Myerson stamp of approval*. May be it shouldn't play a role, but it does. Sue me?

Answer (score 0):

[REOPENED]

[This question was closed as unclear](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/925950/the-height-of-a-polynomial). It seems to me that it's clear what is asked: how to compute the height (what was up with all these comments about a misspelling?) of an algebraic number. Perhaps these people think the question isn't interesting, too easy... But it's not unclear. Someone even managed to answer the question and the OP was happy with the answer, so it can't have been that unclear?

Comment: What's unclear is why someone would give a simple formula for some quantity, and then ask how to compute that quantity. If I posted, "The trace of $\pmatrix{a&b\cr c&d\cr}$ is $a+d$. How do I compute the trace of $\pmatrix{a&b\cr c&d\cr}$?" then you might be forgiven for thinking that my question was unclear, or, rather, that it was unclear how I could possibly be asking what I seemed to be asking. As for the spelling, if you look at the edit history, you'll find in the original it was spelled "hight" all the way through. But you are correct that someone gave an answer that satisfied OP.

Comment: @Gerry Yes, I saw that "hight" was later edited to "height", but I'm saying that commenting again and again on that misspelling was pointless. And the OP was responding very quickly in the comments and clarifying his issue, I don't understand the point of closing as unclear when the OP is obviously very confused himself.

Comment: I would think a confused OP would be the best possible reason to close as unclear. But I think the question was closed (or "put on hold", whatever) way too fast. New users should be given 24 hours to clarify posts before we close them for "unclear" or "no effort".

Comment: @Gerry I disagree, IMO if the OP is confused and you can explain away the confusion, the best thing to do is explain, not close as unclear; even if the OP's confusion makes it so that it's not clear what precisely is asked. Here it looks like that just giving an example of computation was enough for the OP to understand.

Comment: If I were to post, "What's the volume of a square, in terms of its standard deviation?" that would show a certain degree of confusion on my part, and I'd expect my question to be closed as "unclear" owing to that. Although I would hope to be given a chance to clarify it.

Comment: @Gerry I think that's different. Here you are asking a question, but it doesn't make any sense. It's not clear *what* you're asking. There, the OP asked a question, but it's not clear *why* he's asking, since he already gave himself the definition of what he's asking for...! From my point of view, it means that he didn't really understand what he wrote and that he needs it to be explained, even if he doesn't know how to ask for it.

Comment: What do you want from me? I've already indicated that the voters should have exercised more patience. Let it go!

Comment: @Gerry I don't want anything, I'm just trying to explain my reasoning... Sorry if I have offended or annoyed you...

Comment: Anyway, it appears the question has been reopened.

Answer (score 0):

[REOPENED]

This [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/963326/number-of-intersections-of-two-circles) by a new user was put on hold within about an hour of being posted, despite OP's demonstrated willingness to improve it. I suggest we reopen it and give OP the chance to post an answer.

And I suggest, as I have several times in the past, that we cut new users some slack.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/970426) post to be reopened. OP didn't provide context, and hence the question was put on hold. I added some context to improve it. In my opinion, seeing applications of Baire Category Theorem in this context is valuable.

Comment: For questions of the "no context but someone's added some" type, I prefer to wait a week before voting to re-open, because "context" should be about the OP and the question (what they know, is it homework, etc.) The "a week" is so that their homework deadline will have passed, and also there is no rush - the question can still be opened next week...

Comment: @user1729: Good point. :)

Comment: I am glad you think so! Also, I wish people would not downvote these questions. It does seem like a good question, but if it were to be reopened it would have a horrendous score. Ah well...

Answer (score 0):

[UNDELETED (still closed)] [RE-DELETED]

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/704634/small-groups-for-church was clarified BEFORE the last vote to delete was cast. Please, read the edit at the end of the question and you will see that it is perfectly clear.

Comment: Even clarified, it's still a PSQ from March posted by a user who has been inactive since March. It seems like a reasonable deletion candidate to me. Now I see that it was edited by you rather than by the absent OP - to me, that makes the edit much less compelling as a reason to revisit the question.

Comment: I don't see where it matters who edited it, @Carl. If anything, given that I edited it AND answered it, it can hardly be called a PSQ any more. It's a serious, if low-level, mathematical question with a serious answer that someone might find useful some day. I'm not asking for re-opening, just for undeletion.

Comment: Oops. I see that at the actual question, I did assert that the question was ready for re-opening. Well, why not? But in any event, right here, right now, I'm just asking for undeletion.

Comment: Current status: closed, with 3 votes to re-open, and one vote to re-delete.

Comment: I agree that this question should be reopened. I believe that PSQs are only an issue for the short time before the theoretical homework is due in: after a couple of weeks they are fair game for improvement and reopening. This has been approved, so why not reopen?

Comment: Can't undelete due to a recent moderator having cast a vote before he became one.

Answer (score 0):

[REOPENED]

[Closed form for sine graphic rotated by 45 degrees?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1078543/closed-form-for-sine-graphic-rotated-by-45-degrees)

The rules say "when posting a new question, express why answers to the other questions do not satisfy you".

I asked for a closed form of an expression, and said why the answers to the other question do not satisfy me. Why it still has been closed?

Comment: Pardon me, but doesn't Jack D'Aurizio's comment answer your question? Depending on what you qualify as "closed form" the answer is either that series or possibly that no closed form answer exists.

Comment: @Jyrki Lahtonen series is not closed form, ever. An answer that no closed form is possible would be good.

Answer (score 0):

[REOPENED]

[This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/44923/242) deserves to be reopened since the OP did in fact show effort/context in the comments below this question (which were apparently overlooked).

Comment: They were overlooked because they are not in the question itself. Editing the question to include them takes a few seconds, and is much more productive than what you're doing here.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi A more sensible argument is that *your* time is better spent doing that, since you apparently deem it more worthwhile than do I. No doubt that would be time better spent than fruitless arguments about which effort is more "productive" (which this thread is not intended for - see my comments when I created it years ago).

Comment: I didn't say "better spent", I said "more productive". I'm just giving you the reason why the OP's effort was overlooked, you can take my advice as you please. What do you want, more questions reopened, or asserting your position here on meta?

Answer (score 0):

Meta is probably not the best place for [Learning roadmap request: compiling a “Mathematics Stack Exchange Undergraduate Bibliography”](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18946/learning-roadmap-request-compiling-a-mathematics-stack-exchange-undergraduate).  It seems like it was migrated from main and subsequently put on hold because of the format of the answer that OP provided (at least that's what all of the complaints in the comments were about).  That answer has now been deleted.  I vote -- without actually being able to vote -- for moving it back to main and un-"on hold"-ing it.

I'll admit that my suggestion is nearly entirely based on the fact that I think I gave a pretty good answer and I'd like to see it stick around. :)

Answer (score 0):

[REOPENED]

I request that the following question,

- [Way to compute Stirling numbers of the second kind from a multiset](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1086776/way-to-compute-stirling-numbers-of-the-second-kind-from-a-multiset#comment26027_17568),

be reopened. It is currently marked as a duplicate to

- [Stirling numbers of the second kind on Multiset](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/16890/stirling-numbers-of-the-second-kind-on-multiset).

However, they are distinct questions. The open question is asking for explanations about the concept in general, whereas the closed question is asking for specific algorithms for computing the combinations.

Answer (score -1):

[REOPENED] [This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/373761/23500) is a genuine mathematical question that deserves a genuine answer (it was, inexplicably, closed as "non-constructive").

Comment: Well this question seems to be closed now.

Answer (score -1):

[REOPENED]

*Before I begin, if you disagree with this by all means downvote, but can you also please comment to say* why *you disagree. I want to know what you think - make me change my mind!*

I believe that [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/461002/an-elementary-number-theory-question) question has been closed because it is believe that any full would be "too long for this format". However, an expansion of Gerry's comment would be a nice, short answer, so there is a perfectly good answer which is not "too long for this format". (The question asks a recently-solved problem of Catalan which was open for over 100 years. So what is wrong with answering to give a bit of history?!)

Comment: Except that the OP does not ask for "a bit of history" but, apparently, for a proof. And this is definitely not suited to MSE format. (For a change I would be curious to see the reasons of the "re-openers".)

Comment: No...the OP says "Could anyone advise on the proof?". Which *could* be interpreted as "can you prove it", but isn't exactly the same..... With respect to your "change", I personally believe that the onus should be on those closing questions to give a solid reason which doesn't always happen (for example [this](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/10298/10513) re-open request had an anonymous downvote and I had to start ask a [meta question](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/10366/on-the-reception-of-real-world-application-questions) to find out why the question was closed.)

Comment: Also, there is no harm in giving someone the benefit of the doubt. Sure, they are not going to get the whole solution and they didn't ask for some history, but there is no harm in giving them such an answer, and it would be a benefit to the site. The site is, after all, meant to be a big place to put knowledge, so let the repository grow!

Answer (score -1):

[Reopened; reclosed ]

[This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/588230/parse-tree-parenthesis-notation#588230) was closed as unclear. It should be clear to anyone who’s seen parenthesis notation for trees — admittedly more common in linguistics than in mathematics, but hardly unheard of there — and I’d like to answer it. I’d answer it in a comment, but in this case a good answer requires a diagram.

Comment: Despite normally being against this, the only reason I am voting to reopen is that you said that you want to answer that question.

Comment: @Asaf: Many thanks!

Comment: Brian, no need for many. One would suffice. ;-)

Comment: @Asaf: It was an easy way to beat the character limit! (‘Thanks!’ came up one short.)

Comment: Thank you very much! (five letter beyond the limit) ;-)

Comment: Voted to re-close. This is a stereotypical PSQ, and it is in the general benefit of the site for regulars to show self-restraint in not answering these.

Comment: @Carl: In my view both of your assertions are false. (1) The OP is apparently completely lost, and I judge that this is a case in which a full explanation now is probably the best way to help. (2) Not by any measure that I’m willing to accept; rather the opposite, in fact.

Answer (score -1):

Can someone please open https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/641452/colored-picture-for-equivalence-classes-relations-partitions

My questions are numbered in bold. What's purported unclear?

**Sequel — Fev-6-2014 —** I edited. The question has more original text now.

Comment: Pretty much everything is unclear. What are all those boxes? What are all those circles? what are all those squiggly things beneath the circles? What's your, and what comes from the textbook? What is the textbook trying to do, and what are you trying to do, and what exactly are you asking us to do?

Comment: Good, it's better now.

Answer (score -1):

I asked [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/758557/mental-math-tricks) yesterday and it quickly received downvotes for being "opinionated." I then changed it to have the wording "Mental Math Tricks" in the title and "What are some interesting mental math tricks that you know?" as the question. *After* this change, a fifth vote was cast to put the question on hold as "primarily opinion-based" on the basis that "answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise."

Please note that I specifically urged posters to provide justification for their tricks, and that I did not intend (as I clarified in the comments) to select a single "best trick" as the answer - hence my tagging the question under "soft-question" and "big-list".

I also queried "For those of you who downvoted, do you still consider the question opinion based? Is there anything I could do to make it better?" but got no response. I'm fairly new to this forum and I don't actually know what "putting on hold" technically means, but I would be very grateful if this question could be re-opened for contributions. Please note also that it was given 4 upvotes and 2 favorites (the third was my own), suggesting my feelings are shared by at least some members of the community.

Can this be reversed? If the five members who put the post on hold propose to sustain their objections, how do they justify the claim that this question qualifies for "primarily opinion-based"? Also, please indicate if there is a standard process for dealing with this of which I am unaware. I have flagged the question to no avail.

Answer (score -1):

Please reopen https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/705347/redundant-proofs-of-weaker-issues-from-fundamental-theorems-of-calculus-in-spiv.

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/695146/mean-value-theorem-for-proving-a-function-is-lipschitz-and-contractive-s-a-pp

I revised the question. Language and content are clear now. I tried to guess what closers didn't understand because they didn't comment. Please write me if something needs to be bettered.

Answer (score -1):

Please reopen https://math.stackexchange.com/q/709319/85079

I revised the question. Language and content are clear now. I tried to guess what closers didn't understand because they didn't comment. Please write me if something needs to be bettered.

Comment: The statement proposed for a proof is still absurd, for the exact reason explained in comments from the start. (And please note that nobody is [vexed](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/vexed) here.)

Comment: @Did thanks. i revised my question again. rectified now?

Comment: why the downvotes?

Answer (score -1):

Please undelete and reopen  https://math.stackexchange.com/q/678715/85079

I revised the question. Language and content are clear now. I tried to guess what closers didn't understand because they didn't comment. Please write me if something needs to be bettered.

Comment: That question is deleted.

Comment: Dear Tucker, It seems that this question cannot be reopened, because of the manner in which it was deleted.  I have posted a request to reopen your new question on the same topic.  Regards,

Comment: @MattE thank you.

Answer (score -1):

Please reopen https://math.stackexchange.com/q/690026/85079

I revised the question. Language and content are clear now. I tried to guess what closers didn't understand because they didn't comment. Please write me if something needs to be bettered.

Comment: The question has since been deleted.

Answer (score -1):

[REOPENED]

Will you please to reopen [$\binom{n}{k}\binom{n}{n - k}$ vs $\binom{n}{k}$ - Differences? Similarities?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/787708/53259)

I just edited my question to shorten it, but I don't know if this is the concern. Please advise on concerns or suggestions. I'd be grateful if one would please explain what may be "unclear".

I thought to add that user Will Orrick's comments and other comments have helped and enlightened me, so I'd be grateful for a reopening in order for the comments to become answers which I can accept.

Supplementary: The question now has 3 reopen votes.

Answer (score -1):

[REOPENED]

Please reopen the following question:

[Is this module noetherian?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/852267/is-this-module-noetherian)

Also, I would like to know why it was closed.

Comment: Could the downvoter please comment and explain?

Comment: Did you not read the part where it said, "Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level." Does that not give you some idea as to why it was closed?

Comment: Not really. I am interested in the answer to this question, and do not really care what the OP thought about it (also, he gave some of his thoughts in the comments).

Comment: OK, *you* don't care what OP thought about it, but it appears that several other people did. You asked why it was closed; I think the quoted passage goes some way toward answering that question. Also, things might have gone better, had OP edited the question, rather than making people dig through the comments.

Comment: Is this something normal on this site? that questions are closed because the OP didn't tell us what he tried? because browsing around, I see a lot of counterexamples to this phenomena.

Comment: Ah, we are posting past each other on two different threads. Anyway, what gets closed and what stays open is largely a matter of chance, as to which members of the community happen to read which posts.

Comment: OK, so what now? should I repost this question on my own with my thoughts on it? because I want to know the answer (especially about the coherence part).

Comment: You have drawn the attention of the community to the question. Wait a while (say, a few days) to see whether you convince enough people to vote to reopen. If it doesn't happen, then, sure, repost (with links to the previous question).

Comment: See also [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/15102/an-adoption-system-for-on-hold-questions).

Comment: I have one more question - does showing efforts from the OP as a prerequisite is something that was decided in this site? if so, where was this decided?

Comment: @theL: [this list of search results may be useful](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/search?q=PSQ). See also [this question](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/11075/1543) and its list of linked/related questions.

Comment: So this makes me wonder, would the number 2 question on mathoverflow ( http://mathoverflow.net/questions/21003/polynomial-bijection-from-mathbb-q-times-mathbb-q-to-mathbb-q ) be closed here?

Comment: Probably! But you do have to remember that the audiences are different.

Comment: **Please note** that, per design (cf. main question), this thread is not meant for extended discussions on such matters. The goal is to keep this thread tension-free, so that all will feel comfortable posting here. Please use chat or another question for extended discussions.

Answer (score -1):

[UNDELETED] [DELETED] [UNDELETED AGAIN] **[LOCKED]**

I propose undeleting the question [Why is $\;n^2-\frac{n^2}{2} =\frac{n^2}{2}\;$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/379713/12952)

Though the question itself was low level and not particularly exceptional, there were many highly upvoted answers (some creative, some canonical) which I believe are worth preserving.

Comment: Lock it *please* (either way). Delete votes being castable more than once I fear this will never stop otherwise.

Comment: @Alexander As a card-carrying deletionist, I agree with quid: lock in the present (undeleted) state. The historical lock would be the right thing to use for such a question.

Comment: Okay, I locked the question.  Any future meta discussion (including requests to unlock) should take place in these comments.

Answer (score -1):

I think that https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/921772/find-the-value-of-summation, currently on hold, should be reopened. Or un-held or whatever :-) I understand neither the flood of downvotes nor the "on-holding" since I personnally found the question interesting and original enough to spend quite some time on writing an answer to it. Also, it is no more off-topic than many others I have seen on this site : when asked (by me), the OP specifically confirmed that he was searching for a closed form to a fairly complex and intriguing summation.

Finally, I would like to add that I find it harsh to "on-hold" abruptly a question set by a newbie. I for one would be ready to help him improve his question (although I obviously did not find it lacking, and I satisfied myself that he knew what he was writing about).

For all of these reasons, I ask that the "on-hold" be reverted.

Comment: I wonder whether this isn't a problem from an ongoing competition, Project Euler or codechef or something. It just has that smell to it.

Comment: The question is routine computer science homework. The floor function runs through $O(\sqrt{n})$ values; and as long as it stays constant, the usual way of summing $i^4$ applies. As for OP saying they look for closed form -- the OP does not know what s/he is talking about, having not digested their homework assignment.

Comment: The point of "on hold" is exactly to tell the asker to improve the question. If the asker does not act, only then will it be closed et cetera.

Comment: I stand corrected: it's not homework, but a Codechef contest problem. (Which has since been posted a couple times more).

Answer (score -1):

I would like to re-open this question, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/950551/prove-that-x-y-z-is-divisible-by-xyz , which was closed as a duplicate.

The reason I am asking is that the question of which it was judged to be a duplicate has now been deleted.

If this cannot be done, I would like to know why, and how it needs to be changed in order to become an acceptable question. I don't know if this is the appropriate place to ask this second question, so please let me know if I should ask it elsewhere.

This follows an earlier question I asked here: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/16930/how-can-this-question-be-improved

I am the same person as user179549.

Comment: If it is opened, it could be closed as a duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/q/2158/

Comment: I would say that this question is more specific in that it is restricted to three "parts," in addition to being more clearly formulated. Being more specific, it may have simpler answers.

Comment: Did you check the answers to the question I linked?  There are several that are quite simple and the simplest is tailored to the three part case.

Comment: Yes, from the perspective of a person proficient in math, a number of them are clearly equivalent to what would be good answers to the question I'm asking to be re-opened. However, for someone who isn't, it won't be immediately clear whether the short answers take advantage of some property of the numbers $9$, $2$, $3$ and $4$, and some of the longer answers might not be easy to interpret. Both André Nicolas and I had answers that I think would add something to what's in the question you linked to, and the differences are due to the question being different.

Comment: Have a look at this, for instance, as well: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32311/do-not-delete-good-duplicates

Comment: Regarding your last comment, I have no problem with the question being undeleted.  Regarding the question I had linked to, anyone who wants may post a clearer answer (I don't see the same concerns about those answers using 9=2+3+4 to illustrate general ideas, but you may post an answer that is more explicit and complete if desired).

Comment: This question is identical to another question (and it was done on purpose!). That other question was so bad that it got a score of -8, was closed and then deleted by the community. Why should this one be reopened? If you are able to ask the question in a way that won't get it deleted, my opinion is that you should just ask a new question at this point.

Comment: Najib, it was clear that what some people thought made the question "bad" wasn't its mathematical content. So you can't call my question "identical" to the other question based on identical mathematical content, if what was significant about the other was a non-mathematical aspect of it. You said previously that you thought the initial question was bad because it was a homework question. The context of mine is not homework; it is providing an answer to a question I think is interesting, as MSE explicitly invites readers to do here: http://math.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score -1):

[RE-OPENED]

[This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1079010/sum-of-all-sin-values) was closed within five minutes of its posting.  If it had remained open I would have posted an answer.  Nobody will say that I am not good at answering questions here.

Should all questions that have erroneous presuppositions be closed?  Obviously not.

Answer (score -2):

[Now deleted]

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/280561 was just closed with the reason "It's difficult to tell what is being asked here." That's true, it was rather difficult to tell what was being asked there, but I'd just figured it out based on the OP's comments and was in the process of writing an answer that I believe would have cleared things up, when the question was closed.

The question had only been around for $3$ hours, and there was an ongoing exchange of comments attempting to clarify it, with the last comment only half an hour old; I think in a case like this when it's clear that the OP is grappling with the language and trying to make herself or himself understood, questions shouldn't be closed this rapidly for being unintelligible.

Comment: But the OP is not some new user. It's a well known persona.

Comment: @Asaf: Looking at the OP's history, it appears to me that some of his other questions suffered the same fate: They were closed because he's seriously confused about some issues and has a somewhat haughty attitude and a tendency to find fault in mathematics at large rather than himself. I don't, however, see many in-depth attempts to clear up those confusions. Are you implying that the OP has shown bad faith, or at least behaviour that should be sanctioned? If so, where?

Comment: But those are the ones which were not deleted. Furthermore, the OP had several accounts (in part to mask his identity and in part to answer and spread "propaganda" (for the lack of a better term) against ZFC). Some of these accounts were removed and some merged, and so there are questions which are not owned by any user. Going even further the OP is a well-known internet persona from the days of USENET.

Comment: I will add that I have no problem with anyone asking a reasonably phrased question; and I am willing to give the latitude to new users which ask bad questions. I am not willing to accept bad questions from people which have a known history of asking bad questions for the sake of steering arguments.

Comment: @Asaf: Thanks for the explanation. This doesn't seem like an optimal way to deal with this sort of problem to me; I'll think about that and perhaps post a separate meta question.

Comment: That would be good. There is already a meta thread about dealing with cranks, you may want to start there.

Comment: I suggest you read Wolfgang's recent comment to my answer on his recent question (which were so-so, but reasonable). This should give you an idea about the agenda of Mr. Mueckenheim.

Comment: A known crank/troll deservedly gets very little sympathy.

Comment: joriki, you can see WM's recent activity and read some of his comments... after some discussion he begins to show his true agenda.

Answer (score -2):

[REOPENED] I would like to see [What is (the definition of) mathematics?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/287701/what-is-the-definition-of-mathematics/287713#287713) reopened. It has 4 reopen votes now. It needs only one more. There was an enormous amount of debate about the question's merit, but I believe it was asked in earnest, it has been asked before, it will be asked again, so I think having answers is the right thing to do, and in the future, the post can be linked to other such questions, as they arise, for duplication purposes.

***This is a 'request to reopen' post, not a "debate" post.***

Please, if there are strong feelings about this, or for any debate as to how or whether such a question can be answered, let's move the debate to a separate thread to debate whether mathematics can be defined, or its scope delineated in any way so as to serve as a guide for what is appropriate to post at MATHEMATICS.SE.

Comment: amWhy, this thread is meant for less-controversial posts. I believe that after over 30 comments it's time to start a meta thread on that particular thread instead of arguing here.

Comment: @Asaf would it be better if I just omit the second paragraph? I'm just making a legitimate request to re-open a question, on the meta page designed for such requests. I will omit the second paragraph, though.

Comment: amWhy, this is a thread designed for reopen requests which are unlikely to generate a debate. Whether we like that or not after enough comments on the main question maybe it's time to post a separate thread and just move all the comments there instead.

Answer (score -2):

My question [Are real numbers "a joke"?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/415509/are-real-numbers-a-joke) was closed as a duplicate of [Infinite sets don't exist!?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/356264/infinite-sets-dont-exist). I'm voting to re-open my question because I think that even if we accept the existence of infinite sets, Wildberger's opinion on the construction of the real numbers are legitimate.

EDIT: I've clarified my question now. I think it neither a duplicate nor "unconstructive" anymore now. Please re-open.

Comment: @downvoters: please review my question and explain why you are still against re-opening.

Comment: I wonder about a specific claim in Wildberger's note that I don't understand: on page 12 he writes "Think clearly about the subject for a few days, and you will see that the computable real numbers are not countable, and are complete.". This doesn't make sense to me, at least with the standard definitions of "computable", "countable", and "complete". I would be interested to know what he has in mind.

Answer (score -2):

[REOPENED] then [RECLOSED]. Current status: [DELETED]

I believe that [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/707140/how-can-i-prove-that-ab-ab-a-b) should be re-opened. It was closed as being "unclear what your asking", but this has now been rectified.

Comment: The question is still a problem statement only, with no context, so even if it has been clarified it is still out of line with our expectations for questions. It seems bureaucratic to me to vote to reopen a question that still has a clear rationale for closing, when only one of several valid reasons for closing has been addressed.

Comment: @Carl Correction: it is "out of line with *some users* expectations". I see you cast the first vote to reclose it. Not very nice considering the above request.

Comment: @CarlMummert I think this is a bit petty. As questions go it isn't your usual off-the-shelf and out-of-the-book calculus question. The group theory tag is relatively responsible, and for a question like this it is unlikely that a full solution as opposed to a hint would be posted.

Comment: @user1729: I am not sure that the current version of the question, after your edit, is what the original asker was asking http://math.stackexchange.com/posts/707140/revisions . For example, all mention of Ito's theorem is gone. I believe it should be up to the *asker* to clarify what they want to know, rather than for other users to interpret what we think the asker wants to know. The asker has not edited the question since it was put on hold.

Comment: @Bill Dubuque: I posted that comment long before the question was re-opened; there was no response here until *after* the question was reopened and re-closed (including when the post here was edited). We all have to work within the framework of the site and the willingness of others to discuss things.

Comment: @CarlMummert I hadn't noticed the omission of Ito's theorem from the edit - on the one hand it is perhaps not the question the OP had in mind, but on the other no other possible question either makes sense or has an answer...Most likely, Derek Holt's comment was sufficient and they won't return (why would they?).

Comment: @user1729: if, as you suggest, the question the OP had in mind does not make sense or have an answer, I think it should be up to them to clarify it. If you or I had wanted to ask our own question, after all, we could have done it ourselves. If the asker won't return (which does seem plausible here), they are not going to accept any new answers in any case. To me, the absence of the OP is the main reason to let the question stay closed. In this case, though, I *do* wish that someone had commented much earlier to the OP about the need to clarify the question and include context

Comment: @CarlMummert The first comment asked for clarification, 2 minutes after the question was posted...

Comment: @user1729: yes. I have no way to tell whether the OP deleted any comments. Assuming they did not, that request in the comments was never answered - which is a reason to  wait to reopen the question. But I am saying I wish that, beyond asking for a definition, earlier comments had pointed out the other issues in the question. There was even a later comment "6 downvote, you are about to crucify him !!!" by another user, but nobody told the OP the likely reason for the downvotes was that the question itself needed to be improved, until I left one the following day, before the post was reopened.

Comment: My own motivation for voting to delete is that the person who asked the question - an unregistered account with 1 rep and no other activity - has been inactive since the question was asked. Perhaps they got what they wanted out of comments, as suggested above. If not, they can always become active again and ask in improved version of the question with some clarifications.

Comment: @user1729 Now it needs 2 more undelete votes. What a disgrace to the site that valid mathematical questions are being *deleted*.

Comment: I voted to undelete.

Answer (score -2):

Can someone please open https://math.stackexchange.com/q/787937/85100 ? I edited it just now. Please inform me on what's purported unclear?

Comment: What does it mean, "I want to intuit this (fetch)." What does it mean, "Are there illustrations?" That is what is unclear to me (well, that, and why anyone would need any intuition for $a-b\equiv-b\pmod a$).

Comment: This question has since been auto-deleted.

Answer (score -2):

[REOPENED]

Will you please to reopen [Find bases given that P is the change of coordinates matrix from this to this [Lay P244 Q4.7.19]](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/811423/find-bases-given-that-p-is-the-change-of-coordinates-matrix-from-this-to-this-l?noredirect=1#comment1678392_811423)

I just edited my question to shorten it, but I don't know if this is the concern. Please advise on concerns or suggestions. I'd be grateful if one would please explain what may be "unclear".

Comment: As I said in my comment on the original question, you can't really to expect some heavenly insight from the clouds on every problem - at this level, the proof and the computations are virtually indistinguishable. I see that you have asked *numerous* questions asking for intuition about various objects - some people have left comments similar to mine on some of your previous questions. At some point, you'll just have to go through the *steps* and try to understand them; once you do this, the intuition follows naturally.

Answer (score -2):

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/539192/how-many-prime-numbers-exist-all-together-in-proportion-to-not-prime-numbers

This was closed as a duplicate of questions asking how many prime numbers exist.

But this question is different.  It says "in proportion to".  Is there some reasonable way to construe that other than as being about the following?
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} (\text{proportion of numbers $\le n$ that are prime})
$$
I think there may be other reasonable ways to construe it, but simply asking about the number of primes is not one of them.

Comment: Looking at the edit history, I see that it was originally posted as asking how many primes there are, and was correctly closed as a duplicate. Then OP edited it to ask for the proportion of primes to non-primes, making the answers that had been posted before it was closed irrelevant. Another poster rolled it back to the original question, but OP edited it back to the new question. Look, the proportion question has surely been asked and answered on m.se as well. Maybe a moderator should re-open it and then immediately reclose it as a duplicate of a relevant question.

Comment: @GerryMyerson : It is odd that you say the proportion question has surely been asked before, despite the fact that you didn't give us a link.  So a question gets deleted, then the original poster edits it so that it's different, then it gets re-opened.  That's how it's supposed to work, isn't it?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/82074/percentage-of-primes-among-the-natural-numbers and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/28540/prove-that-lim-x-to-infty-pix-x-0 and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/804502/pix-leq-frac-xfx-for-some-unbounded-function-fx  I would have no objection to reopening, if I could be certain it would immediately be reclosed.

Comment: I answered the original form of the question, and in the comments to my answer the OP came up with the new question, which I essentially answered then and there. I have now re-edited my answer to answer both questions (although I believe the thread should have died there and then). I am unsure if anyone (apart from perhaps me and my reputation) would benefit from reopening this question. Therefore, I will not vote to reopen it (but nor do I oppose this).

Comment: The question has since been deleted by votes.

Answer (score -2):

I do not agree with the closure of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1037619/is-physics-really-a-rigorous-subject). [Here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/17445/why-exactly-has-the-question-been-put-on-hold) it is said to be a question more of Physics or Philosophy of Science but I think that my question precisely wants to know whether Physics (to be precise, Theoretical Physics) really is a rigorous subject or not **from a mathematical point of view** as has been already mentioned in the body of the question.

It has been mentioned that the question has nothing to do with Mathematics, but in my opinion it has to do something with the Mathematical Foundation of Physics and that's why naturally I think that it has to do with Mathematics itself.

Also my question asks about the logical justification  of the inclusion of the "axioms" I have stated in my question.

**Note**:-Please note that this kind of question (see for example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/472331/level-of-rigor-in-mathematical-physics)) has previously been asked in this site.

Comment: It seems a kind of partiality that your question is closed while other similar one's are open.

Comment: @user31782: ...and are upvoted.

Comment: IMO votes have the _least_ value. What matters is that the post should not be closed and not be deleted.

Answer (score -2):

[DELETED]

[How meaningful is $\infty=-\frac12$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1074870/how-meaningful-is-infty-frac12) was closed as a duplicate of [$1+1+1+\cdots=−\frac12$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/648665/1-1-1-cdots-frac12). However, the latter merely asks for a prove of said identity, while the former is merely related to it by its implication and asking about its general validity.

Recently a user [indicated that he has a good answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1074870/how-meaningful-is-infty-frac12#comment2250662_1074870).

Comment: Is is worth pointing out that the user who [added the sentence](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/posts/18923/revisions) "Recently a user indicated that he has a good answer" is the same users who [posted the comment](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1074870/how-meaningful-is-infty-frac12#comment2250662_1074870) along the lines: *Reopen this question so that I can answer it.*

Comment: @BillDubuque And the purpose of bumping the old thread when the new thread [also contains the same request](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/19243) is...?

Comment: @NajibIdrissi I didn't see it in the duplicate thread (it shouldn't be there). Nor should there be duplicate threads (the other already has its first page almost full again, so what wasthe point?). But reason does not seem to win  on meta these days.

Answer (score -2):

[REOPENED]

[Username "Jihad"](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18984/username-jihad) was closed for being opinion based. No answer is opinioned based. My answer and quids are based on definitions and the fact that Jihad can be a name (quid). The mods answer is based on research about the said users activity. The close reason doesnt coincide with the facts and answers. I request that users vote to reopen.

Comment: Thanks for the votes to reopen!

Answer (score -3):

I'd like to request that [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/213999/28900) be reopened. It was closed unilaterally as off-topic by a (then-)moderator, and while I agree that it is arguably off-topic, I also feel that it would be better located at Physics.SE, rather than just stuck in the limbo of closed posts at Math.SE.

Comment: Why on earth do you want that post reopened? It is not on-topic here, and we should certainly not migrate a post of such low quality to physics.

Answer (score -3):

[DELETED]

This question:

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1071821/why-these-arguments-for-frac-00-0-are-not-valid

Is much more substatinated and concrete than recently asked question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1083303/what-problems-arise-in-mathematics-if-i-take-frac00-1-or-frac-infty

I think this news question is just an exact duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1071821/why-these-arguments-for-frac-00-0-are-not-valid , but nobody downvotes it. Why?

I wonder why my question received 9 downvotes and was closed while the other question has no downvotes. In my question I explain what is not satisfactory in prevuous questions and answers.

Answer (score -4):

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/988417/an-earth-day-isnt-exactly-24-hours-is-it

The reason why the solar and siderial days differ is just geometry.  Mathematicians can probably answer this better than anyone else can.

Answer (score -5):

[Now deleted]

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/294123/taking-the-amc-12-this-week

I see no reason at all why "this question will likely solicit debate, arguments, polling or extended discussion" of any unhealthy kind (or at all).

Comment: The case to close the question is practically open-and-shut if you go by the criteria in the FAQ, rather than by the summary text taken from the limited selection of options for close votes.

Comment: @Hurkyl, the FAQ lists some positive criteria that support this question, and some negative criteria that either do not apply, or would have to be interpreted overly broadly to make them apply.

Answer (score -5):

Will you please to reopen https://math.stackexchange.com/q/930809/53259?

My English is imperfect so I'm trying to educate myself on possible mathematical traps and snares in common English questions. Please advise on concerns or suggestions.

Comment: I fail to see how that question fits the scope of the site. We probably allow too many questions only tangentially related to mathematics, but these are another level. I know you're trying to find a home for these sorts of questions ([exhibit A](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/q/1195/2751), [exhibit B](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/239571/214632)), but they really don't fit here. Maybe try to find some sort of LSAT prep forum.

Answer (score -5):

[reopened] Thanks

Why was [Understanding the community stand point on posts about self harming](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/18829/understanding-the-community-stand-point-on-posts-about-self-harming) unilaterally put on hold by a moderator's close vote?

The following passage is a direct copy of about meta:

**What is "meta"? How does it work?**

Meta Mathematics Stack Exchange is the part of the site where users discuss the workings and policies of Mathematics Stack Exchange rather than discussing math itself. It is separated from the main Q&A to reduce noise there while providing a legitimate space for people to ask how and why this site works the way it does. Meta is for...

- ...Mathematics Stack Exchange users to communicate with each other
  about Mathematics Stack Exchange (asking questions about how the
  websites work, or about policies and community decisions)
- ...Mathematics Stack Exchange users to communicate with Stack
  Exchange the company (posting bugs, suggesting improvements, or
  proposing new features), and
- ...Stack Exchange to communicate with the community (soliciting
  feedback on new ideas or features, or discussing policies that affect
  the whole network)

The first bullet point is about asking questions about policies and community decisions which the linked question is about.

Comment: Alas, it's not the only unilateral action by the new mod. He also unilaterally deleted the main question just below on convergent sequences.

Comment: @BillDubuque I am having buyers remorse over my selection of one of the three. He wanted to close one of my meta post as well for no reason.

Comment: Oh no, a moderator employing his powers. What have we come to? Why elect someone moderator if you don't want him to use the new tools he has at his disposal?

Comment: @NajibIdrissi I want them used properly.

Comment: How can something that was closed by three users be considered a "unilateral moderator action"? Maybe it's because I'm not a native English speaker, but I believe that unilateral means "*(of an action or decision) performed by or affecting only one person, group, or country involved in a particular situation, without the agreement of another or the others.*" and if a moderator casts the third closing vote, then it's not quite unilateral.

Comment: @AsafKaragila because a mod by passes the normal user count for closure votes.

Comment: Sure, but that's not *unilateral*. There were already standing closing votes.

Comment: @AsafKaragila It is unilateral in the fact it doesn't matter what happened a priori since a mods vote is essential final. That is, based on one opinion, we get a hold which progresses to a close. There is no consensus anymore.

Comment: If it would have been a fifth vote, would it still be unilateral?

Comment: @Asaf What is the point of arguing about the (standard, overloaded) terminology when there can be no doubt what is meant? Comments like that will just sidetrack the main discussion.

Comment: @BillDubuque I believe it is because he doesn't like me for some reason. He tends to do this with me for whatever reason on other post as well.

Comment: @Bill, first of all I was under the impression that "unilateral" meant as a single vote. Not as a third, fourth or fifth vote. Apparently being a non-native English speaker means you're not allowed to raise an opinion. Secondly, suppose that this is not reopened, will you concede it should be "unilaterally" closed if two more votes to close appear? Finally, dustin, I really have no problem with you. You may refer to my discussion with you on that answer you posted on that closed thread, but I have an issue with *that* issue. It has nothing to do with you.

Comment: Uh. So it *is* possible to cast reopen votes on a post that was closed by a moderator. It's also impossible to withdraw reopen votes, apparently... You learn something new everyday. (I'm not 100% clear on how my reopen vote can be the only one at this point in time, considering the discussion -- I'm also not sure why this whole exchange blew up, considering that).

Comment: @NajibIdrissi Correct on both counts. Moderator closures can be overturned by regular users. (Moderator deletions cannot be.)

Comment: @Behaviour Which leads me to wonder what the big deal is, and why my vote is the first. I guess complaining on meta is more important than actually achieving something?

Comment: @Najib: I think that most people were not aware of this change (I *now* recall something like this being mentioned before, but I didn't remember that neat little fact when I first saw this post and its comments).

Comment: @AsafKaragila What change? Moderator closevotes were always subject to being overturned. [Random example from 2012](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/posts/6152/revisions).

Comment: @Behaviour: Interesting. Thanks.

Comment: As an aside: the definition of "unilateral" implies that a "unilateral vote to close" means that the power was exercised without consulting other users (i.e. a *single* vote to close).  When a mod closes as the 2nd, 3rd, or 4th vote, that cannot be considered *unilateral*.  (Yes, I know I'm just reasserting what Asaf said, but I wanted to chime in to signal that he isn't alone in his understanding of the meaning of unilateral.)

Comment: @anorton read definition two. You will see that it applies to party. http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/unilateral

Comment: @dustin Ok, great.  Now that we've decided that every collective or individual action on the site (i.e. every action period) is unilateral, you might as well remove it from your post as it's redundant. Or did you want it to have the usual force of the word unilateral as it's commonly used on MSE without it having the usual meaning?

Comment: @ScottH. If that is how you want to extrapolate this, that is fine.

Comment: @Dustin I have no personal grudge against you. Now I'm busy but I'll address your concerns in a while.

Comment: Please, [see this.](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/18926/regarding-the-closure-and-deletion-of-two-particular-posts) Regards,

Answer (score -8):

[Undeleted, Reopened, Reclosed, Redeleted, Re-undeleted (but still closed) and flagged for moderator attention]

I think that [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/151938/how-many-digits-of-pi-are-currently-known) should be reopened.

The question asked "How many digits of $\pi$ are currently known?". I believe that [my answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/151938/how-many-digits-of-pi-are-currently-known/152402#152402) is interesting enough to save the poor question ("poor" because "currently" is ill-defined - and my answer side-steps this!).

I should also point out that the question has such a low score because the OP was, quite frankly, odd (this is explained in the [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/151938/how-many-digits-of-pi-are-currently-known/152402#comment353492_151938) by Ilya).

Comment: Ilya's comment is every possible reason for having this deleted.

Comment: @Asaf The SE model is based around the idea the the OP does not "own" the question (and answerer's do not "own" their answers). That, combined with the age of the question, makes me feel that it is not justified deleting the question based on the actions of the OP. (Also, it seems that this was the OPs only activity here, although they logged on on 3rd May...)

Comment: I don't fully buy that approach here. But I really don't want to get into an argument. Suffice to say, I don't think this should be undeleted. (With all my appreciation to your contributions to the site, and to that particular thread.)

Comment: @Asaf I am not interested in having an argument either :-) Can I ask you one final question though: would your opinion be different if the OP had been normal? If there was none of the noise?

Comment: I *might have considered* that, but in all likelihood, I wouldn't. This is ultimately an easily Google-able question, whose answer can change when someone wishes to test the new Intel Knight Landing to its full power, and calculates more digits than before.

Comment: @Asaf That is the point of my answer - that, in a certain sense, you don't have to think about it in terms of computing power! (Although I may be stretching the phrase "in a certain sense" to its limits with this comment...)

Comment: Yes, it's quite a stretch. I think that if this question should be on the site, then it should be better written. Your answer is good and all, but in that case, the questions should be fixed. And since visibility of highly downvoted questions is low. It's better that you just post a question like that which has proper formulation, and then re-post your answer. This question, as written, is garbage, and the product of a mind eager to post a question, so they could gain some points or transfer a bounty to a second account.

Comment: So if you really think this answer should be on the site, why not post it on a question that deserves being on the site as well?

Comment: @AsafKaragila That thought did occur to me. But, at the moment, I am trying to wind down my activity here (something along the lines of research+teaching leave, and extended paternity leave...). So maybe I will post a similar question when I have more free time.

Comment: I apologize for voting to close again; I vaguely remembered the question, but I should have checked the history before voting a second time. Somehow I expected the software would prevent it. I do think the question should be deleted, but I did not intend to vote twice. Now I cannot see how to retract my vote.

Comment: Now [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/151938/how-many-digits-of-pi-are-currently-known) is reopened.

Comment: And now closed, for the 4th time (!), once as Not A Real Question, once as Off-Topic, once as Exact Duplicate, and now as Unclear What You're Asking. It has 24 upvotes, and 31 downvotes; it has an answer with 24 upvotes (and 2 downvotes), and another answer with 34 upvotes (and 6 downvotes). It cannot be said that this question hasn't received any attention!

Comment: And then deleted again, and then undeleted. Holy cow!

Answer (score -10):

[Auto-Deleted]

There is a question:

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/987284/fuel-level-in-horizontal-cylindrical-tank/987290#987290

I did answer it some time ago. The question is a PSQ. The question is closed because the OP hadn't shown any research effort. I've no problem with the downvotes that question got. The problem is that the answers on that answer weren't worthy of downvotes. My answer could have some mistakes but my method to calculate the volume by using integration is completely correct. The other answer IIRC had 2 upvotes initially. Mine had 1 upvote. It is obvious that the question has become a victim of the [massive-deletion campaign](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/15126/103816).

Please undelete the question, for the answer can be(are for me at-least) useful for the future visitors.

Comment: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question In particular the "provide context" part.

Comment: If you are advocating closing the question, does it matter what the stated reason for closure is?

Comment: @GerryMyerson I'm not advocating to close it; rather I want it to be reopened, but if it is closable according to some policy of this website then they should give the correct reason. IIRC Posting homework questions without providing research effort was allowed on MSE but seems like the policies have been changed as I cannot find the homework tag itself!

Comment: The homework tag got banished some months ago --- you can probably find the discussion we had here on meta. There is a posse that goes around closing questions-without-effort, and the "provide context" reason is the one they generally give.