# Cleaning up the "Requests for Reopen Votes" thread?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, re-open

I suggest that a moderator once in a while cleans up the [Requests for Reopen & Undeletion Votes, etc. (volume 10/2012 - 12/2014)](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6424/requests-for-reopen-votes) thread to avoid the thread getting cluttered. If a question has been reopened, then maybe that post could be deleted after a short time (like a week or so). Likewise, if a question has not been opened after a month, then maybe the request could be deleted.

Added: I just realized that a high-rep user might still be able to see the deleted requests. So maybe one could just delete the while thread and start a new (identical one) once in a while. Just a thought.

Comment: This is already discussed in the last handful of comments to the first post ("question") of that thread.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think it is necessary to delete posts or start a new thread, since you can sort posts by clicking the active tab, which will display the most recent posts first (these are the ones that are likely in need of attention).

And secondly as you have mentioned in your post, $10$K+ users will anyway be able to see these deleted posts and given that those who have the ability to open closed questions, also have the ability to view deleted posts, this will prove to be redundant.

Comment: Ahh... I hadn't seen that one could sort the posts. I see that the reason fpr my suggestion doesn't make sense.