# Question deleted without "no reasons"?

Tags: support, deletion

I just noticed that this question was deleted but I can't understand why.

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/752079/recursion-as-function-valued-of-function

What can be the reason and how I can "undelete" it?

Comment: Most people cannot see what is linked to. Perhaps describe the situation a bit. Who deleted it? What was the score? Had it answers? (If the answers are Community, nonpositive, none, then it was very likely autodeleted.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It was automatically deleted by the [Community♦](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community) user. The question was 30 days old, had a negative score and no answer. Such questions are [removed automatically](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5222/214632).

<del>Since ordinary users cannot undelete ♦-moderator deleted posts, you cannot undelete it yourself, you need to flag it for moderator attention if you want it to be undeleted.</del> [Ordinary 10k+ users can now undelete Community♦-deleted posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/235254), but it requires three undelete votes (or moderator intervention), so if you want it undeleted, post in the [Requests for Reopen & Undeletion Votes](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6424/requests-for-reopen-undeletion-votes-etc) thread making your case (or flag for moderator attention; not recommended as first option).

Note, however, that if the status remains (negative score, no answers), it will be deleted again by Community♦ when the script next runs (weekly, I think), so unless there is reason to expect a change of that status, <del>moderators</del> people will be hesitant to undelete.

Comment: ok thanks for the info.

Comment: I think the Community deletion runs everyday, at 03:00.

Comment: @JonasMeyer That's the daily script, which deletes eligible closed questions (9 days old, etc). The low-scoring questions that meet 30- or 365- day criteria are deleted by a weekly script. It runs about 0:00  on Saturdays (UTC).