# Edited names not updating

Tags: bug, display-names

I have noticed a few times that edited names are not being updated. For example:

main: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2658/10513

meta: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/15013/10513

Neither of the answerer's goes by the names "signed" on the posts anymore (click on the link to their profiles to see). Their "signatures" have not been updated with their names. What is going on here?

(It is perhaps relevant that both questions have multiple pages of answers, and the question on main is "protected".)

Comment: SE surely knows that (some/all?) CW posts do not pick-up name changes. This has been mentioned on meta in the past, and I've mentioned it to SE folks long ago. So it seems that they are in no rush to fix it.

Comment: @Bill Ahh, didn't know that. I was assuming that you didn't post under the name "Gone" though (so that that post *would* have been updated at some point), but I assume then that this assumption was incorrect.

Comment: In fact I just edited it and it still doesn't pick up the current name, so the bug still exists. But, curiously, in the active questions list the "modified by..." username is current.

Comment: Is this the same as this? http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/2928/old-usernames-and-names-of-deleted-users-in-cw-mode An answer in that post links to http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/47474/do-old-usernames-stick-to-cw-posts-by-design/47522#47522 where it says that it is ([meta-tag:status-bydesign]).

Comment: @Martin Yes, the questions are the same. The comments to the linked linked post actually claim "don't care" rather than "by design". Ah well.