# A question about why a question was closed

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closing

I am wondering why [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/298011/find-a-translation-that-fixes-y-cos-x) question was closed. It is closed as "unclear", but to me it seems perfectly clear (and I cannot see why it is not).

I do not mean to claim that it is a wonderful, well-thought-out question. But rather, I do not think that it should have fallen foul of the recent spate of chaff-ridding.

Hence, my question:

> Why was this question closed?

(Relevant: I posted in the ["Reopen request"](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/16535/10513) thread, and the request obtained a +1/-2 without comment...)

Comment: For others reading this: the question was **reopened**.

Answer (score 1):

Earlier, deletion seemed easier than retagging and editing the question. Now that deletion met some resistance... sure, let's reopen.

Comment: Yes. [Let's](http://img3.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20120808122745/community-sitcom/images/d/d0/Let%27s_Potato_Chips.png).

Comment: I think if you are going to continue with your crusade you should be doing it *properly*. If your reason was simply "laziness" then I am slightly frustrated. Your edits improve the question, sure, but it wasn't that bad to begin with - it didn't deserve closure!

Comment: @user1729 Yes, I am _disgustingly_ lazy. If you tend to get frustrated with other people's laziness, reading Math.SE is guaranteed to be frustrating...

Comment: @900 My criticism was not that you are lazy, but rather of a poor job done through laziness. I mean, a better lazy option would have been to just ignore it. (As a side issue, I am lazy to. I only come to math.SE as a form of procrastination. Because typing is easier than digging through the bombsite of ny desk to find the work I am supposed to be doing. I suspect this is a common issue...)