# About output of a function of Magma

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

About two months ago, I asked a question about the output of a function of the software Magma. The question stayed on hold for a few days and then it was closed.
The problem is that I searched the documention for that function and it simply does not have (enough) information about the output. I also tried to search on google, but had no sucess.

My question is: where is the appropriate place in Stack Exchange to ask this?

I would like to emphasize that this function has to do with the places of a given degree of an algebraic function field.

Comment: BTW there also exists a tag ([tag:magma-cas]). This suggests that (at least some of) the questions about this sofware might be on-topic here.

Comment: If you edit the question, now that it has been undeleted, it will be placed on the reopen review queue. Of course, it only needs one more reopen vote.

Comment: Undeleted, reopened, upvoted. Now all that's missing is somebody knowing the answer.

Comment: No idea why it was closed.  Upvoted and added a bounty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is most likely on math. There is a separate site for Mathematica questions, so those often get migrated. However, being software used by mathematicians, Magma questions are on-topic here. You need 250 reputation to cast a [reopen vote](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/view-close-votes) on your question, but you can post an "answer" to [Requests for Reopen & Undeletion Votes, etc.](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6424/requests-for-reopen-undeletion-votes-etc) and explain why [Output for places in Magma's online calculator](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/942405) should be reopened. You can cite this question, if it gets enough upvotes.

Comment: Needs to be undeleted first. Closed, no votes -> [Community♦](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community) deleted.

Comment: @DanielFischer: it had 2 votes, so I undeleted it. Thanks.

Comment: But, unless it gets reopened or upvoted soon, it will be re-deleted next time the script runs.

Comment: I will have to check, but I thought that my almighty, unilateral vote might not get undone by Community.

Comment: Ah, that might be. Anyway, it has an upvote now, so for the time being it won't be deleted.

Comment: Yeah, it's a decent question, so I upvoted it, too. It is safe whether my vote counts differently with the script or not.

Comment: I didn't know that there is the [tag:magma-cas] tag as @MartinSleziak said. I can add this tag to the question. And thanks a lot for your help! I met Stack Exchange a few months and I'm really enjoying it!